# What is Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, evented-io

I don't fully get what [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) is all about. Maybe it's because I am mainly a web based business application developer. What is it and what is the use of it?

My understanding so far is that:

1. The programming model is event driven, especially the way it handles [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output).
2. It uses [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) and the parser is [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29).
3. It can be easily used to create concurrent server applications.

Are my understandings correct? If yes, then what are the benefits of evented I/O, is it just more for the concurrency stuff? Also, is the direction of Node.js to become a framework like, JavaScript based (V8 based) programming model?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

I think the advantages are:

1. Web development in a dynamic language (JavaScript) on a VM that is incredibly fast (V8). It is much faster than Ruby, Python, or Perl.
2. Ability to handle thousands of concurrent connections with minimal overhead on a single process.
3. JavaScript is perfect for event loops with first class function objects and closures. People already know how to use it this way having used it in the browser to respond to user initiated events.
4. A lot of people already know JavaScript, even people who do not claim to be programmers. It is arguably the most popular programming language.
5. Using JavaScript on a web server as well as the browser reduces the impedance mismatch between the two programming environments which can communicate data structures via JSON that work the same on both sides of the equation. Duplicate form validation code can be shared between server and client, etc.

Comment: @postfuturist: It actually performs well against lots of alternatives. It beats Java 6 pretty handily in lots of cases, too. Neat!

Comment: @postfuturist I think you have compared against java 6 -Xint. Try comparing with java 6 -server

Comment: @iJK yammer.com is a working application of node.js

Comment: Funny, I was writing JScript in ASP 10 years ago so I could (a) avoid the awfulness of VBScript, (b) use the same language on the client and server, and (c) re-use my own and others' JS libraries for string handling ...etc.

Comment: @AntonyQuinn Funny, I didn't know anyone else who did JScript in ASP, though the down side there was dealing with COM enumerations was a pain.  Other than that, it worked well.

Comment: @Why did you edit this post for "Legacy bullshit" only? I don't think 212 people would have vote for this post if you did write this from the beginning.

Answer (score 617):

I use Node.js at work, and find it to be very powerful. Forced to choose one word to describe Node.js, I'd say "interesting" (which is not a purely positive adjective). The community is vibrant and growing. JavaScript, despite its oddities can be a great language to code in. And you will daily rethink your own understanding of "best practice" and the patterns of well-structured code. There's an enormous energy of ideas flowing into Node.js right now, and working in it exposes you to all this thinking - great mental weightlifting.

Node.js in production is definitely possible, but far from the "turn-key" deployment seemingly promised by the documentation. With Node.js v0.6.x, "cluster" has been integrated into the platform, providing one of the essential building blocks, but my "production.js" script is still ~150 lines of logic to handle stuff like creating the log directory, recycling dead workers, etc. For a "serious" production service, you also need to be prepared to throttle incoming connections and do all the stuff that Apache does for [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). To be fair, [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) has this *exact* problem. It is solved via two complementary mechanisms: 1) Putting Ruby on Rails/Node.js behind a dedicated webserver (written in C and tested to hell and back) like [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) (or [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) / [Lighttd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighttpd)). The webserver can efficiently serve static content, access logging, rewrite URLs, terminate [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL), enforce access rules, and manage multiple sub-services. For requests that hit the actual node service, the webserver proxies the request through. 2) Using a framework like [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) that will manage the worker processes, recycle them periodically, etc. I've yet to find a Node.js serving framework that seems fully baked; it may exist, but I haven't found it yet and still use ~150 lines in my hand-rolled "production.js".

Reading frameworks like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) makes it seem like the standard practice is to just serve everything through one jack-of-all-trades Node.js service ... "app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))". For lower-load services and development, that's probably fine. But as soon as you try to put big time load on your service and have it run 24/7, you'll quickly discover the motivations that push big sites to have well baked, hardened C-code like [Nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) fronting their site and handling all of the static content requests (...until you set up a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), like [Amazon CloudFront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_CloudFront))). For a somewhat humorous and unabashedly negative take on this, see [this guy](http://teddziuba.com/2011/10/node-js-is-cancer.html).

Node.js is also finding more and more non-service uses. Even if you are using something else to serve web content, you might still use Node.js as a build tool, using [npm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_%28software%29) modules to organize your code, [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to stitch it into a single asset, and [uglify-js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) to minify it for deployment. For dealing with the web, JavaScript is a perfect [impedance match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) and frequently that makes it the easiest route of attack. For example, if you want to grovel through a bunch of [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) response payloads, you should use my [underscore-CLI](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) module, the utility-belt of structured data.

#### Pros / Cons:

- Pro: For a server guy, writing JavaScript on the backend has been a "gateway drug" to learning modern UI patterns. I no longer dread writing client code.
- Pro: Tends to encourage proper error checking (err is returned by virtually all callbacks, nagging the programmer to handle it;  also, async.js and other libraries handle the "fail if any of these subtasks fails" paradigm much better than typical synchronous code)
- Pro: Some interesting and normally hard tasks become trivial - like getting status on tasks in flight, communicating between workers, or sharing cache state
- Pro: Huge community and tons of great libraries based on a solid package manager (npm)
- Con: JavaScript has no standard library. You get so used to importing functionality that it feels weird when you use JSON.parse or some other build in method that doesn't require adding an npm module. This means that there are five versions of everything. Even the modules included in the Node.js "core" have five more variants should you be unhappy with the default implementation.  This leads to rapid evolution, but also some level of confusion.

#### Versus a simple one-process-per-request model ([LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)):

- Pro: Scalable to thousands of active connections. Very fast and very efficient. For a web fleet, this could mean a 10X reduction in the number of boxes required versus PHP or Ruby
- Pro: Writing parallel patterns is easy. Imagine that you need to fetch three (or N) blobs from [Memcached](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached). Do this in PHP ... did you just write code the fetches the first blob, then the second, then the third? Wow, that's slow. There's a special [PECL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEAR#PECL) module to fix that specific problem for Memcached, but what if you want to fetch some Memcached data in parallel with your database query? In Node.js, because the paradigm is asynchronous, having a web request do multiple things in parallel is very natural.
- Con: Asynchronous code is fundamentally more complex than synchronous code, and the up-front learning curve can be hard for developers without a solid understanding of what concurrent execution actually means. Still, it's vastly less difficult than writing any kind of multithreaded code with locking.
- Con: If a compute-intensive request runs for, for example, 100 ms, it will stall processing of other requests that are being handled in the same Node.js process ... AKA, [cooperative-multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#Cooperative_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing). This can be mitigated with the Web Workers pattern (spinning off a subprocess to deal with the expensive task). Alternatively, you could use a large number of Node.js workers and only let each one handle a single request concurrently (still fairly efficient because there is no process recycle).
- Con: Running a production system is MUCH more complicated than a [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) model like Apache + PHP, [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), etc. Unhandled exceptions will bring down the entire process, necessitating logic to restart failed workers (see *[cluster](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html)*). Modules with buggy native code can hard-crash the process. Whenever a worker dies, any requests it was handling are dropped, so one buggy API can easily degrade service for other cohosted APIs.

#### Versus writing a "real" service in Java / C# / C (C? really?)

- Pro: Doing asynchronous in Node.js is easier than doing thread-safety anywhere else and arguably provides greater benefit. Node.js is by far the least painful asynchronous paradigm I've ever worked in. With good libraries, it is only slightly harder than writing synchronous code.
- Pro: No multithreading / locking bugs.  True, you invest up front in writing more verbose code that expresses a proper asynchronous workflow with no blocking operations.  And you need to write some tests and get the thing to work (it is a scripting language and fat fingering variable names is only caught at unit-test time). BUT, once you get it to work, the surface area for [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) -- strange problems that only manifest once in a million runs -- that surface area is just much much lower. The taxes writing Node.js code are heavily front-loaded into the coding phase. Then you tend to end up with stable code.
- Pro: JavaScript is much more lightweight for expressing functionality. It's hard to prove this with words, but [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), dynamic typing, lambda notation, prototypal inheritance, lightweight modules, whatever ... it just tends to take less code to express the same ideas.
- Con: Maybe you really, really like coding services in Java?

For another perspective on JavaScript and Node.js, check out *[From Java to Node.js](http://n0tw0rthy.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/from-java-to-node-js/)*, a blog post on a Java developer's impressions and experiences learning Node.js.

---

**Modules**
When considering node, keep in mind that your choice of JavaScript libraries will *DEFINE* your experience. Most people use at least two, an asynchronous pattern helper (Step, Futures, Async), and a JavaScript sugar module ([Underscore.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js)).

Helper / JavaScript Sugar:

- [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) - use this. Just do it. It makes your code nice and readable with stuff like _.isString(), and _.isArray(). I'm not really sure how you could write safe code otherwise. Also, for enhanced command-line-fu, check out my own [Underscore-CLI](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli).

Asynchronous Pattern Modules:

- [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step) - a very elegant way to express combinations of serial and parallel actions. My personal reccomendation. See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989538/nodejs-parallel-callback-design-pattern/7167192#7167192) on what Step code looks like.
- [Futures](https://github.com/coolaj86/futures) - much more flexible (is that really a good thing?) way to express ordering through requirements. Can express things like "start a, b, c in parallel. When A, and B finish, start AB. When A, and C finish, start AC." Such flexibility requires more care to avoid bugs in your workflow (like never calling the callback, or calling it multiple times). See [Raynos's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989538/nodejs-parallel-callback-design-pattern/5994989#5994989) on using futures (this is the post that made me "get" futures).
- [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) - more traditional library with one method for each pattern. I started with this before my religious conversion to step and subsequent realization that all patterns in Async could be expressed in Step with a single more readable paradigm.
- [TameJS](http://tamejs.org/) - Written by OKCupid, it's a precompiler that adds a new language primative "await" for elegantly writing serial and parallel workflows. The pattern looks amazing, but it does require pre-compilation. I'm still making up my mind on this one.
- [StreamlineJS](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs) - competitor to TameJS. I'm leaning toward Tame, but you can make up your own mind.

Or to read all about the asynchronous libraries, see [this panel-interview](http://www.infoq.com/articles/surviving-asynchronous-programming-in-javascript) with the authors.

Web Framework:

- [Express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express) Great Ruby on Rails-esk framework for organizing web sites. It uses [JADE](http://jade-lang.com/) as a XML/HTML templating engine, which makes building HTML far less painful, almost elegant even.
- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) While not technically a node module, jQuery is quickly becoming a de-facto standard for client-side user interface. jQuery provides CSS-like selectors to 'query' for sets of DOM elements that can then be operated on (set handlers, properties, styles, etc). Along the same vein, Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) CSS framework, [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) for an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, and [Browserify.js](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to stitch all your JavaScript files into a single file. These modules are all becoming de-facto standards so you should at least check them out if you haven't heard of them.

Testing:

- [JSHint](http://github.com/jshint/node-jshint) - Must use; I didn't use this at first which now seems incomprehensible. JSLint adds back a bunch of the basic verifications you get with a compiled language like Java. Mismatched parenthesis, undeclared variables, typeos of many shapes and sizes. You can also turn on various forms of what I call "anal mode" where you verify style of whitespace and whatnot, which is OK if that's your cup of tea -- but the real value comes from getting instant feedback on the exact line number where you forgot a closing ")" ... without having to run your code and hit the offending line. "JSHint" is a more-configurable variant of [Douglas Crockford](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)'s [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).
- [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) competitor to Vows which I'm starting to prefer. Both frameworks handle the basics well enough, but complex patterns tend to be easier to express in Mocha.
- [Vows](http://vowsjs.org/) Vows is really quite elegant. And it prints out a lovely report (--spec) showing you which test cases passed / failed. Spend 30 minutes learning it, and you can create basic tests for your modules with minimal effort.
- [Zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie) - Headless testing for HTML and JavaScript using [JSDom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/) as a virtual "browser". Very powerful stuff. Combine it with [Replay](https://github.com/assaf/node-replay#readme) to get lightning fast deterministic tests of in-browser code.
- A comment on how to "think about" testing:

  - Testing is non-optional. With a dynamic language like JavaScript, there are *very* few static checks. For example, passing two parameters to a method that expects 4 won't break until the code is executed. Pretty low bar for creating bugs in JavaScript. Basic tests are essential to making up the verification gap with compiled languages.
  - Forget validation, just make your code execute. For every method, my first validation case is "nothing breaks", and that's the case that fires most often. Proving that your code runs without throwing catches 80% of the bugs and will do so much to improve your code confidence that you'll find yourself going back and adding the nuanced validation cases you skipped.
  - Start small and break the inertial barrier. We are all lazy, and pressed for time, and it's easy to see testing as "extra work". So start small. Write test case 0 - load your module and report success. If you force yourself to do just this much, then the inertial barrier to testing is broken. That's <30 min to do it your first time, including reading the documentation. Now write test case 1 - call one of your methods and verify "nothing breaks", that is, that you don't get an error back. Test case 1 should take you less than one minute. With the inertia gone, it becomes easy to incrementally expand your test coverage.
  - Now evolve your tests with your code. Don't get intimidated by what the "correct" end-to-end test would look like with mock servers and all that. Code starts simple and evolves to handle new cases; tests should too. As you add new cases and new complexity to your code, add test cases to exercise the new code. As you find bugs, add verifications and / or new cases to cover the flawed code. When you are debugging and lose confidence in a piece of code, go back and add tests to prove that it is doing what you think it is. Capture strings of example data (from other services you call, websites you scrape, whatever) and feed them to your parsing code. A few cases here, improved validation there, and you will end up with highly reliable code.

Also, check out the [official list](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/appendix_1.html) of recommended Node.js modules. However, [GitHub's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) [Node Modules Wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) is much more complete and a good resource.

---

*To understand Node, it's helpful to consider a few of the key design choices:*

Node.js is **EVENT BASED** and **ASYNCHRONOUS** / **NON-BLOCKING**. Events, like an incoming HTTP connection will fire off a JavaScript function that does a little bit of work and kicks off other asynchronous tasks like connecting to a database or pulling content from another server. Once these tasks have been kicked off, the event function finishes and Node.js goes back to sleep. As soon as something else happens, like the database connection being established or the external server responding with content, the callback functions fire, and more JavaScript code executes, potentially kicking off even more asynchronous tasks (like a database query). In this way, Node.js will happily interleave activities for multiple parallel workflows, running whatever activities are unblocked at any point in time. This is why Node.js does such a great job managing thousands of simultaneous connections.

***Why not just use one process/thread per connection like everyone else?*** In Node.js, a new connection is just a very small heap allocation. Spinning up a new process takes significantly more memory, a megabyte on some platforms. But the real cost is the overhead associated with context-switching. When you have 10^6 kernel threads, the kernel has to do a lot of work figuring out who should execute next. A bunch of work has gone into building an O(1) scheduler for Linux, but in the end, it's just way way more efficient to have a single event-driven process than 10^6 processes competing for CPU time. Also, under overload conditions, the multi-process model behaves very poorly, starving critical administration and management services, especially SSHD (meaning you can't even log into the box to figure out how screwed it really is).

Node.js is **SINGLE THREADED** and **LOCK FREE**. Node.js, as a very deliberate design choice only has a single thread per process. Because of this, it's fundamentally impossible for multiple threads to access data simultaneously. Thus, no locks are needed. Threads are hard. Really really hard. If you don't believe that, you haven't done enough threaded programming. Getting locking right is hard and results in bugs that are really hard to track down. Eliminating locks and multi-threading makes one of the nastiest classes of bugs just go away. This might be the single biggest advantage of node.

***But how do I take advantage of my 16 core box?***

Two ways:

1. For big heavy compute tasks like image encoding, Node.js can fire up child processes or send messages to additional worker processes. In this design, you'd have one thread managing the flow of events and N processes doing heavy compute tasks and chewing up the other 15 CPUs.
2. For scaling throughput on a webservice, you should run multiple Node.js servers on one box, one per core, using [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) (With Node.js v0.6.x, the official "cluster" module linked here replaces the learnboost version which has a different API). These local Node.js servers can then compete on a socket to accept new connections, balancing load across them. Once a connection is accepted, it becomes tightly bound to a single one of these shared processes. In theory, this sounds bad, but in practice it works quite well and allows you to avoid the headache of writing thread-safe code. Also, this means that Node.js gets excellent CPU cache affinity, more effectively using memory bandwidth.

***Node.js lets you do some really powerful things without breaking a sweat.*** Suppose you have a Node.js program that does a variety of tasks, listens on a [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) port for commands, encodes some images, whatever. With five lines of code, you can add in an HTTP based web management portal that shows the current status of active tasks. This is EASY to do:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end(myJavascriptObject.getSomeStatusInfo());
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Now you can hit a URL and check the status of your running process. Add a few buttons, and you have a "management portal". If you have a running Perl / Python / Ruby script, just "throwing in a management portal" isn't exactly simple.

***But isn't JavaScript slow / bad / evil / spawn-of-the-devil?*** JavaScript has some weird oddities, but with "the good parts" there's a very powerful language there, and in any case, JavaScript is THE language on the client (browser). JavaScript is here to stay; other languages are targeting it as an IL, and world class talent is competing to produce the most advanced JavaScript engines. Because of JavaScript's role in the browser, an enormous amount of engineering effort is being thrown at making JavaScript blazing fast.  [V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) is the latest and greatest javascript engine, at least for this month. It blows away the other scripting languages in both efficiency AND stability (looking at you, Ruby). And it's only going to get better with huge teams working on the problem at Microsoft, Google, and Mozilla, competing to build the best JavaScript engine (It's no longer a JavaScript "interpreter" as all the modern engines do tons of [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiling under the hood with interpretation only as a fallback for execute-once code).  Yeah, we all wish we could fix a few of the odder JavaScript language choices, but it's really not that bad. And the language is so darn flexible that you really aren't coding JavaScript, you are coding Step or jQuery -- more than any other language, in JavaScript, the libraries define the experience. To build web applications, you pretty much have to know JavaScript anyway, so coding with it on the server has a sort of skill-set synergy.  It has made me not dread writing client code.

Besides, if you REALLY hate JavaScript, you can use syntactic sugar like [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/). Or anything else that creates JavaScript code, like [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (GWT).

***Speaking of JavaScript, what's a "closure"?*** - Pretty much a fancy way of saying that you retain lexically scoped variables across call chains. ;) Like this:

```
var myData = "foo";
database.connect( 'user:pass', function myCallback( result ) {
    database.query("SELECT * from Foo where id = " + myData);
} );
// Note that doSomethingElse() executes _BEFORE_ "database.query" which is inside a callback
doSomethingElse();
```

See how you can just use "myData" without doing anything awkward like stashing it into an object? And unlike in Java, the "myData" variable doesn't have to be read-only. This powerful language feature makes asynchronous-programming much less verbose and less painful.

Writing asynchronous code is always going to be more complex than writing a simple single-threaded script, but with Node.js, it's not that much harder and you get a lot of benefits in addition to the efficiency and scalability to thousands of concurrent connections...

Comment: "the 'myData' variable doesn't have to be read-only" -- seems like you would want to keep it immutable most of the time to prevent concurrency issues though, right?

Comment: @Nick - that is false.  "concurrency issues" are mitigated by the fact that node is single threaded.  Locking in node simply does not exist; it is not needed in a single-threaded paradigm.

Comment: Cluster has been integrated into node core in node 0.6 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8470986/212702 http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster

Comment: @qarma - I do.  My post has evolved over the last 6 months as I have gotten more experience running a production service with Node.  We were evaluating Node as a PHP alternative, and I've used this post to help collect my own thoughts on the platform.

Comment: p.s, side note - I actually edited it enough times that the post became "community wiki" (the threshold is 10 edits).  I mistakenly thought this was some kind of honor, when actually it just blocks the reputation gain from upvotes.  Eventually, one of the pre-CW-status voters clicked "unvote" (hopefully, by accident :) and I lost reputation ... confused I filed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129941/bug-with-reputation-calculation-for-downvote-on-highly-rated-answers-200 and was schooled in what "Community Wiki" actually means.  Mods were kind enough to remove the CW status.  :)

Comment: You might be interested (for the sake of knowledge) in a Ruby framework "Goliath" that toutes async code written in a procedural fashion (using Ruby's fibers) such that you get all the benefits of async code without any extra complexity in the programming model. (https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath)

Comment: @John - seems interesting, though the docs leave much to be desired.  I think that ultimately something fiber-ish is going to have to win... some elegant way of describing a serial workflow of "asynchronous" steps ... and most importantly with support for stack traces and easy debugging.

Comment: @ddopson - Yeah, the project has been in development for some time now and just hit version 1, so I imagine the docs might be almost non-existent. (Here's another docs page if you didn't see it as well http://postrank-labs.github.com/goliath/doc/index.html). And yes, debugging is going to be critical, however that will be true for any async code whether it employs callbacks or not (even though implicit callbacks may be slightly more confusing).

Comment: @John - my debugging comment absolutely applies to vanilla asnyc as well.  To break debugging, all I need to do is wrap some function call in "process.nextTick(...)".  Then when it throws, my stack trace will start with process.nextTick; not so helpful.  What I really want to know is: "which stack scheduled process.nextTick?"   I call that data "causal chains", and it reminds me of 'causedBy' in Java exception handling ... low level code throws, mid level code catches the LL exception and throws FrameworkMethodFailedException - without 'causedBy', the stack from the LL code would be lost.

Comment: Great post. Very helpful overview that I have learned a lot from. I will mention though that I think your comparison to "service" languages like Java and C# was very one sided. Your first listed pro is arguably the strongest - async dev is a node.js design goal, so that makes sense. Your second listed pro is ridiculous. Paraphrasing, it says "investing up front in good code eliminates threading bugs". True, but not a language feature. Lastly, the third pro is also a list of C# features (prototypal inheritance not withstanding).

Comment: @jmacinnes - Node has no locking code at all, thus no locking bugs.  Frequently, Java services will use multiple threads, and thus require at least some level of locking.  True, one could write an event-loop based Java service and have similar tradeoffs to Node, but frequently that's not what is done.

Comment: "JS has no standard library" maybe the community should make one?

Comment: "JS has no standard library".  Because JS is both flexible and highly supported it has created a culture capable of supporting myriad competing & philosophically distinct libraries, and this is, I think, a forceful driver of the continued evolution of JS.  Survival and dominance of the fittest libraries, rather than artificially enshrining a standard library, strengthens rather than weakens JS as a whole.

Answer (score 85):

[V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29) is an implementation of JavaScript. It lets you run standalone JavaScript applications (among other things).

Node.js is simply a library written for V8 which does evented I/O. This concept is a bit trickier to explain, and I'm sure someone will answer with a better explanation than I... The gist is that rather than doing some input or output and waiting for it to happen, you just *don't* wait for it to finish. So for example, ask for the last edited time of a file:

```
// Pseudo code
stat( 'somefile' )
```

That might take a couple of milliseconds, or it might take seconds. With evented [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) you simply fire off the request and instead of waiting around you attach a callback that gets run when the request finishes:

```
// Pseudo code
stat( 'somefile', function( result ) {
  // Use the result here
} );
// ...more code here
```

This makes it a lot like JavaScript code in the browser (for example, with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) style functionality).

For more information, you should check out the article *[Node.js is genuinely exciting](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Nov/23/node/)* which was my introduction to the library/platform... I found it quite good.

Comment: How is evented IO implemented without using locks, using threading, process, closures? And I have a feeling that the concepts are quite similar to that of functional programming and Erlang.

Comment: It's implemented as a simple event loop, as far as I know. v8 has the callback/etc functionality already, just like any javascript implementation.

Comment: The IO event loop of node.js means that at any given point of time at most only one thing is being done. I see two significant gains: There is no overhead of thread switching, so node.js is very fast, and secondly many typical concurrency bugs Java is notorious for are not possible.

Comment: "How is evented IO implemented without using ... closures?"
JavaScript supports closures and they are used all the time in node.js (anonymous functions ans in the example here).

Comment: @panzi: Didn't notice Jeffrey included closures in his list of things node.js is implemented 'without'. Obviously every function in javascript is a closure around it's scope :)

Comment: Also, the Node IO model is VERY similar to the Erlang design point, minus Erlang's fancy messaging concepts.

Answer (score 35):

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is an open source command line tool built for the server side JavaScript code. You can download a [tarball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarball), compile and install the source. It lets you run JavaScript programs.

The JavaScript is executed by the [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), a JavaScript engine developed by Google which is used in [Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) browser. It uses a JavaScript API to access the network and file system.

It is popular for its performance and the ability to perform parallel operations.

> [Understanding node.js](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb) is the best explanation of [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) I have found so far.

Following are some good articles on the topic.

> - [Learning Server-Side JavaScript with Node.js](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/learning-serverside-javascript-with-node-js/)
> - [This Time, You’ll Learn Node.js](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/this-time-youll-learn-node-js/)

Answer (score 13):

The closures are a way to execute code in the context it was created in.

What this means for concurency is that you can define variables, then initiate a nonblocking [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) function, and send it an anonymous function for its callback.

When the task is complete, the callback function will execute in the context with the variables, this is the closure.

The reason closures are so good for writing applications with nonblocking I/O is that it's very easy to manage the context of functions executing asynchronously.

Answer (score 8):

Two good examples are regarding how you manage templates and use progressive enhancements with it. You just need a few lightweight pieces of JavaScript code to make it work perfectly.

I strongly recommend that you watch and read these articles:

- [Video glass node](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/29/video-glass-node/)
- [Node.js YUI DOM manipulation](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/09/node-js-yui-3-dom-manipulation-oh-my/)

Pick up any language and try to remember how you would manage your HTML file templates and what you had to do to update a single [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) class name in your [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) structure (for instance, a user clicked on a menu item and you want that marked as "selected" and update the content of the page).

With Node.js it is as simple as doing it in client-side JavaScript code. Get your DOM node and apply your CSS class to that. Get your DOM node and innerHTML your content (you will need some additional JavaScript code to do this. Read the article to know more).

Another good example, is that you can make your web page compatible both with JavaScript turned on or off with the same piece of code. Imagine you have a date selection made in JavaScript that would allow your users to pick up any date using a calendar. You can write (or use) the same piece of JavaScript code to make it work with your JavaScript  turned ON or OFF.

Answer (score 7):

There is a very good fast food place analogy that best explains the event driven model of Node.js, see the full article, *[Node.js, Doctor’s Offices and Fast Food Restaurants – Understanding Event-driven Programming](http://code.danyork.com/2011/01/25/node-js-doctors-offices-and-fast-food-restaurants-understanding-event-driven-programming/)*

Here is a summary:

> If the fast food joint followed a traditional thread-based model, you'd order your food and wait in line until you received it. The person behind you wouldn't be able to order until your order was done. In an event-driven model, you order your food and then get out of line to wait. Everyone else is then free to order.

Node.js is event-driven, but most web servers are thread-based.York explains how Node.js works:

- You use your web browser to make a request for "/about.html" on a
  Node.js web server.
- The Node.js server accepts your request and calls a function to retrieve
  that file from disk.
- While the Node.js server is waiting for the file to be retrieved, it
  services the next web request.
- When the file is retrieved, there is a callback function that is
  inserted in the Node.js servers queue.
- The Node.js server executes that function which in this case would
  render the "/about.html" page and send it back to your web browser."

Answer (score 6):

Well, [I understand that](http://nodejs.org/#about)

> - Node's goal is to provide an easy way
>     to build scalable network programs.
> - Node is similar in design to and influenced by systems like Ruby's Event Machine or Python's Twisted.
> - Evented I/O for V8 javascript.

For me that means that you were correct in all three assumptions. The library sure looks promising!

Comment: A lot of the times I find about page is quite vague.

Answer (score 6):

Also, do not forget to mention that Google's V8 is VERY fast. It actually converts the JavaScript code to machine code with the matched performance of compiled binary. So along with all the other great things, it's INSANELY fast.

Answer (score 3):

Q: The programming model is event driven, especially the way it handles [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output).

Correct. It uses call-backs, so any request to access the file system would cause a request to be sent to the file system and then Node.js would start processing its next request. It would only worry about the I/O request once it gets a response back from the file system, at which time it will run the callback code. However, it is possible to make synchronous I/O requests (that is, blocking requests). It is up to the developer to choose between asynchronous (callbacks) or synchronous (waiting).

Q: It uses JavaScript and the parser is V8.

Yes

Q: It can be easily used to create concurrent server applications.

Yes, although you'd need to hand-code quite a lot of JavaScript. It might be better to look at a framework, such as http://www.easynodejs.com/ - which comes with full online documentation and a sample application.