# Permanently running my node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, permanent

I have created a node application its working fine on my local server. Now i want to upload on live server and it will work permanently. I have found some links and do the same steps that are mentioned but still its not working([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently)).

I have setup forever module on my local server.Its installed successfully and run all commands. but when i close my terminal my application works stop.

Also i my application i have created app.js file. According to link i have remove `app.js` file and move to `server/server.js`. but still its not working.

```
    terminal@mymac:/var/www/node/chat$ forever start server.js 
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server.js
```

I got only this message when i start.

Comment: There are many packages for this but `forever` and `pm2` are most popular...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
nohup forever start server.js &
```

To read the logs of `node`, you can `tail` the `nohup.txt` file generate when running the `nohup` command

PS: If you apply this you will have to kill the process manually:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```