# How to keep parse server and dashboard online?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, backend, vps, parse-server

i'm using parse server and parse dashboard for my push notification and DB stuffs, my problem is when i establish an ssh connection to my VPS and run them both everything is fine until i turn off my computer or disconnect from the server dashboard and parse server will terminated! is there any solution to make them online permanently?

commands i use:
for starting the parse server ->

```
npm start
```

for starting the parse dashboard ->

```
parse-dashboard --config config.json --allowInsecureHTTP
```

even i tried to duplicate nodejs running but it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you running the parse server? It sounds like your process is terminated along with your SSH connection, so you aren't running it as a service

Comment: You can use a tool like [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) which nicely does the trick for me. This will work for pretty much every node.js application.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it's what you said, so how can i run it as a service?

Comment: Please show the commands you use to run it

Comment: @cricket_007 Please see the edited question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a node.js application run permanently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently)

Comment: Also relevant.  https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually, whenever you exit your SSH session, your active session will be killed. Using screen command will create a session that will not be killed even you closed your terminal / exit SSH. And you can do exactly what you usually do.

described in this link:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/162

enter screen at SSH session.some instruction and info will display, dismiss it with spacebar. here you go, a new screen that will remain running even you exit your SSH session.you might run the following command:

```
cd /var/www/parse/parse-dashboard npm start --config some/path/to/parse-dashboard-config.json --allowInsecureHTTP=1
```

thanks to @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

Include the `ParseDashboard` inside your `ParseServer`. If you are using the parse-server-example, install `parse-dasboard` inside `parse-server-example` using `npm install parse-dashboard` and copy this inside index.js

```
var ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var dashboard = new ParseDashboard({
    "apps": [{
            "serverURL": "https://yourserver.url",
            "appId": "myAppId",
            "masterKey": "myMasterKey",
            "appName": "YourAppName"
        }
    ],
    "users": [{
        "user": "user",
        "pass": process.env.USER_PASS || "pass"
    }]
}, allowInsecureHTTP);

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
    liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["Post", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
    }
});
```

Comment: Would this not be available and exposed to anyone then? Dashboard uses the secret master key which is not used in exposed applications. The dashboard should be used externally from the parse server IMO.