# Running a React app as a background process

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, reactjs, npm

I'm completely new to deploying front-end code and thus the question.
I have a React App which I need to run as a background process, however I'm a little confused about the how to do this.
I run a npm script

```
npm run build
```

to build, minify and serve the project on a server. 
The relevant code for the build process is this.

```
"prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test lint build:html",
"build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
"postbuild": "babel-node tools/distServer.js"
```

This is the code inside the distServer.js

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import open from 'open';
import compression from 'compression';


const port = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    open(`http://localhost:${port}`);
  }
});
```

This works and the project runs, however the moment I close my terminal the project stops.
The build process creates, three files,

```
index.html
index.js
styles.css
```

Now if I navigate to the index.html and open it in a browser, but naturally, nothing shows up. So I'm assuming that I'd have to run it as a node process. How do I do this on the production server and run it as a background process so that even if I exit the terminal the app continues to run.
I have checked this issue,
[How to make a node.js application run permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently)

But this has a javascript file as the entry point, in my case it's a html file. I'm not sure how can I modify my scripts to run the front-end app permanently as a background process. Any help appreciated.

Comment: For development at least, "background process" can also just be another tab in your terminal emulator, it doesn't always need to be a daemon set up with the init system. Obviously you need that for prod, but...

Answer (score 3):

Your Javascript file (`distServer.js`) **is** your entry point – it's the file that you run to start your server. Your HTML file (`index.html`) is only served as a response to the requests.

`babel-node` is OK for development, but it's not suitable for production. You can precompile your Javascript files to vanilla Javascript, then use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) or [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) as described in the [question you already linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently) in order to keep the server running even after you close your terminal.

How you organize your source files and compiled files is up to you, but here's one way to do it (quote from the [documentation for an example Node server with Babel](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server#getting-ready-for-production-use)):

> ### Getting ready for production use
>
> So we've cheated a little bit by using `babel-node`. While this is
>   great for getting something going. It's not a good idea to use it in
>   production.
>
> We should be precompiling your files, so let's do that now.
>
> First let's move our server `index.js` file to `lib/index.js`.
>
> ```
> $ mv index.js lib/index.js
> ```
>
> And update our `npm start` script to reflect the location change.
>
> ```
>   "scripts": {
> -   "start": "nodemon index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
> +   "start": "nodemon lib/index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2"
>   }
> ```
>
> Next let's add two new tasks `npm run build` and `npm run serve`.
>
> ```
>   "scripts": {
>     "start": "nodemon lib/index.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015,stage-2",
> +   "build": "babel lib -d dist --presets es2015,stage-2",
> +   "serve": "node dist/index.js"
>   }
> ```
>
> Now we can use `npm run build` for precompiling our assets, and `npm run serve` for starting our server in production.
>
> ```
> $ npm run build
> $ npm run serve
> ```
>
> This means we can quickly restart our server without waiting for
>   `babel` to recompile our files.
>
> Oh let's not forget to add `dist` to our `.gitignore` file.
>
> ```
> $ touch .gitignore
>
> dist
> ```
>
> This will make sure we don't accidentally commit our built files to
>   git.

Comment: After some struggle I have come up with something similar, the issue is I just can't seem to be able to install babel-node on linux. I used babel-node in development while using a mac and it seemed to work, but looks like it doesn't work on linux. Is there a bypass around that?

Comment: @StochasticNerd You have the `babel-cli` npm package in your dependencies and installed, right?

Answer (score 0):

try running 'npm install -g pm2' then followed by 'pm2 start npm --(your app name) -- start'

the react app will run in background even when you closed the terminal.