# Forcing node.js to auto restart

Tags: node.js, nodes, restart, pm2, nodemon

so i'm currently working on a node and i tried pm2 and nodemon for auto restarting my node when it crashe's but none of them has seemed to work fine for me. I'm going to pust some prints...
[enter image description here][1]

I want node to restart when the follow error shows up

BEFORE ERROR:
https://i.snag.gy/Idus9z.jpg

AFTER ERROR:
https://i.snag.gy/9rIF2N.jpg

Comment: try forever nodejs

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/12701278/7425593

Comment: I tried forever and i finded the same results

Comment: There was an error in your node.js code,post your code

Answer (score 1):

we are commonly use node-dev and nodemon for auto restarting node server,  Here we can seen that, error cause because of the object have not value. so it make undefined error. In your code bot.js file line 338 have one **if condition** , here you check an object value equal to 3. but that property cannot read. because they don't have any value. so please check that property properly assigned or not.

Node-dev is a development tool for Node.js that automatically restarts the node process when a file is modified

npm install -g node-dev

For run

node-dev file_name.js

Comment: If i wanted to use forever or something to make my node run long , how would that be? Once node-dev worked for me to auto restart