# Can Node.js server only exist in the cmd window? And everything will be gone when cmd window is shut?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it somewhat inconvenient in contrast with running as a service of the OS, which seems more stable and non-fragile?

I’m sorry I just begin to explore Node.js. I know Node.js is certainly great, I’m just not familiar with it. So excuse me for this maybe stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a service-ize tool named **forever**, then the node.js app will keep running even after you quit from cmd.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is the answer you are looking for.

[How to make a node.js application run permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently)

Possibly duplicate question.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!