# nodejs application on web server causing fork bomb - bash: fork: retry: No child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, apache

I'm hosting a website on a web host using a nodejs application (expressjs, request, etc.). The web host has an apache terminal from where I can call `node app.js &` or `forever start app.js` and the app runs fine. 
However, once the terminal is closed, the number of  processes being used balloons to about 30, meaning that the next time I open the terminal, instead of being greeted with `[hostname@server ~] $` I instead get:

```
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: retry: No child processes
bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
bash-4.2$
```

Somehow I believe a fork bomb is being created, and I can't seem to figure out where or why? I'm not using `fork()` anywhere, and if I use `forever` to start my app, the logs show no signs of errors or new processes being created.

When this happens, I can't use any terminal commands half the time, until I manage to pkill/pgrep.

I tried calling `bash-4.2$ top`, and got this:

```
top - 13:41:13 up 71 days, 20:57, 0 users, load average: 1.82, 1.81, 1.72
Tasks: 14 total, 1 running, 2 sleeping, 11 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 11.7 us, 2.7 sy, 0.1 ni, 85.5 id, 0.1 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem : 41034544 total, 2903992 free, 6525792 used, 31604760 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 0 total, 0 free, 0 used. 28583704 avail Mem

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
1001511 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 3692 1384 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.02 bash
1001578 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2840 524 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001598 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2672 348 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001599 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2896 524 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001600 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2720 396 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001607 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2928 532 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001613 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2964 532 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001618 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2780 348 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001619 xxxxxxxx 20 0 12012 3024 544 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001620 xxxxxxxx 20 0 11880 2804 372 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001651 xxxxxxxx 20 0 12012 2836 352 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1001653 xxxxxxxx 20 0 12016 3392 896 T 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1004463 xxxxxxxx 20 0 9904 1840 1444 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 bash
1005200 xxxxxxxx 20 0 56364 1928 1412 R 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 top
```

Which looks like somehow `bash` processes are being repeatedly made?

My actual nodejs `app.js` is a typical expressjs web app, with code such as (shortened example code):

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('..//'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser());
```

...

```
app.post('/profile', function(req,res){
    "use strict";
    var id = req.query.id;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM xxxxxxx WHERE xxxxx=" + id, function(err,result){
        res.send(result);               
    }); 
});
```

...

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    "use strict";
    res.redirect('/404.html');
});

console.log('Listening on 8080');
app.listen(8080);
```

Any ideas on why this issue is occurring? I'm relatively new to node so any help is appreciated, and apologies if any noob mistakes have been made.

Comment: Does this happen when you don't use forever -- as in when you use node app.js & and exit, does it still happen?

Comment: using `node app.js &` still causes the error, however it eventually stops the app (domain posts a 503 error) while `forever` keeps the app running

Comment: You need to determine if the NodeJS process is actually restarting or if the NodeJS app is forking. To do this I recommend writing something simple to a file at the start of your NodeJS app load. If there are 30 entries in that file, the the OS is restarting NodeJS over and over. As a side note: NodeJS **is single threaded** and cannot spawn/fork a process on its own. Most people use NodeCluster for this purpose these days. Previously you would see the use of `child_process`.

Comment: Check out the EDIT of this answer for why forever might be restarting your app https://stackoverflow.com/a/32029341/370321

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for the idea, I implemented a script which wrote to a debug text file on the app load, but only 1 line was appended. It seems however from the `top` command that the processes being created are `bash` processes?

Comment: @abelito I had a look in the logs (~/.forever/) and it doesn't seem as though the app is actually being restarted? At no point in the log is `Forever detected script exited` which I've had in the past

Comment: Next test - remove all `console.log()` statements or any other statements that would use the console.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that the problem is actually stemming from my `~/.bashrc` file which contains these lines:

```
# User specific aliases and functions

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

If these lines are commented out, then the problem ceases to occur. However I obviously can't use node commands because nvm isn't started.

Somehow that code is looping creating multiple bash instances whenever the terminal is accessed.

Answer (score -2):

Do you use Visual Code Extension "Visual Studio IntelliCode" ?
If yes try removing it. No more "Fork Bombs". Do not ask me why. I only know that after 3 hours hitting my head, i finally found a way to stop node forking processes.

CONTEXT: Visual Code on Windows, accessing a VPS with Ubuntu Server via Remote SSH Plugin at VS Code. NVM installed. If i remove NVM and/or remove the export line at ~/.bashrc nothing happens. Thousands of Zumbi processes are created. I remove Visual Studio IntelliCode Extension and Voilá! All OK.