# Load balance request traffic with muiltiple Node servers using NGINX

Tags: node.js, nginx

According to this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines#8685968)**:

> You should run multiple Node servers on one box, 1 per core and split request traffic between them. This provides excellent CPU-affinity and will scale throughput nearly linearly with core count.

Got it, so let's say our box has 2 cores for simplicity.

I need a complete example a `Hello World` app being load balanced between two Node servers using NGINX.

This should include any NGINX configuration as well.

Comment: Question has a concrete, fact-based answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var port = parseInt(process.argv[2]);

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port);

console.log('Server running at http://localhost:' + port + '/');
```

nginx configuration

```
upstream app  {
  server localhost:8001;
  server localhost:8002;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://app;
  }
}
```

Launch your app

```
node app.js 8001
node app.js 8002
```

[HttpUpstreamModule documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

Additional reading material

- [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) - still experimental, but you don't need nginx
- [forever module](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) - in case your app crashes
- [nginx and websockets](http://metacogni.tv/blog/2013/02/19/websockets-with-nginx-plus-ssl-also/) - how to proxy websockets in the new nginx version