# Does Apigee Edge Node container support multi core processing capability

Tags: node.js, multicore, apigee

I was looking at this 
reference for understanding [Node.js on multi-core machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines).

Does Apigee Edge Node container support multi core processing capability?

How to configure this?

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that multicore functionality in node is done via the [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module. According to the [Apigee node.js docs](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/developing-nodejs-applications-apigee-edge#node-js-reference), the cluster module functionality is disabled. Also, looking at the same [page](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/developing-nodejs-applications-apigee-edge#node-js-reference), child_process is disabled.

These lead me to believe that multicore processing support in Apigee is not available.