# Nodejs to utilize all cores on all CPUs

Tags: multithreading, node.js

I'm going to create multithreaded application that highly utilize all cores on all CPUs doing some intensive IO (web browsing) and then intensive CPU (analyzis of crawled streams). Is NodeJS good for that (since it's single threaded and I don't wanna run couple of nodejs instances [one per single core] and sync between them). Or should I consider some other platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node is perfect for that; it is actually named Node as reference to the intended topology of its apps, as multiple (distributed) nodes that communicate with each other.

Take a look at the built-in [`cluster`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module, which handles multi-instance applications and thread sharing.

##### Further reading

- *[Multi Core NodeJS App, is it possible in a single thread framework?](https://codeburst.io/multi-core-nodejs-app-is-it-possible-in-a-single-thread-framework-fe4feaf67f90)* by **Cristian Ramirez** on *Codeburst*
- *[Scaling NodeJS Applications](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/scaling-node-js-applications-8492bd8afadc/)* by **Samer Buna** on *FreeCodeCamp*

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript V8 Engine was made to work with async tasks running on One core. However, it doesn't mean that you can have multiple cores running the same or perhaps, differente applications that communicate between each other.

You just have to be aware of some multiple-cores problems that might occur.

For example, if you are going to share LOTS of information between threads, then perhaps this is not the best language for you.

Considering the factor of multi-core language, I have recently been introduced to Elixir, based on Erlang (http://elixir-lang.org/).

It is a really cool language, developed 100% thinking about multi-thread applications. But it was made to make it easy, and also very fast applications that can be scalonable for as many cores as you want/can.

Back to node, the answer is yes, it support multi-thread, but is up to you to decide what to continue with. Take a look at this answer, and you might clarify your mind: [Node.js on multi-core machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines)