# What is the best way I can scale my nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, scalability, autoscaling

## The basics

Right now a few of my friends and I are trying to develope a browser game made in nodejs. It's a multiplayer top-down shooter, and most of both the client-side and server-side code is in javascript. We have a good general direction that we'd like to go in, and we're having a lot of fun developing the game. One of our goals when making this game was to make it as hard as possible to cheat. Do do that, we have all of the game logic handled server-side. The client only sends their input the the server via web socket, and the server updates the client (also web socket) with what is happening in the game. Here's the start of our problem.

All of the server side math is getting pretty hefty, and we're finding that we need to scale in some way to handle anything more than 10 players (we want to be able to host many more). At first we had figured that we could just scale vertically as we needed to, but since nodejs is single threaded, is can only take advantage of one core. This means that getting a beefier server won't help that problem. Our only solution is to scale horizontally.

#### Why we're asking here

We haven't been able to find any good examples of how to scale out a nodejs game. Our use case is pretty particular, and while we've done our best to do this by ourselves, we could really benefit from outside opinions and advice

## Details

We've already put a LOT of thought into how to solve this problem. We've been working on it for over a week. Here's what we have put together so far:

### Four types of servers

We're splitting tasks into 4 different 'types' of servers. Each one will have a specific task it completes.

#### The proxy server

The proxy server would sit at the front of the entire stack, and be the only server directly accessible from the internet (there could potentially be more of these). It would have haproxy on it, and it would route all connections to the web servers. We chose haproxy because of its rich feature set, reliability, and nearly unbeatable speed.

#### The web server

The web server would receive the web-requests, and serve all web-pages. They would also handle lobby creation/management and game creation/management. To do this, they would tell the game servers what lobbies it has, what users are in that lobby, and info about the game they're going to play. The web servers would then update the game servers about user input, and the game server would update the web servers (who would then update the clients) of what's happening in the game. The web servers would use TCP sockets to communicate with the game servers about any type of management, and they would use UDP sockets when communicating about game updates. This would all be done with nodejs.

#### The game server

The game server would handle all the game math and variable updates about the game. The game servers also communicate with the db servers to record cool stats about players in game. This would be done with nodejs.

#### The db server

The db server would host the database. This part actually turned out to be the easiest since we found [rethinkdb](http://rethinkdb.com/), the coolest db ever. This scales easily, and oddly enough, turned out to be the easiest part of scaling our application.

### Some other details

If you're having trouble getting your head around our whole getup, [look at this](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1CfCOL60yZca8RQ9M1MCKRYNIMQDCnxX-P1pbYA2RcNI/edit), it's a semi-accurate chart of how we think we'll scale.

If you're just curious, or think it might be helpful to look at our game, it's currently hosted in it's un-scaled state here.

### Some things we don't want

- We don't want to use the cluster module of nodejs. It isn't stable (said [here](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)), and it doesn't scale to other servers, only other processors. We'd like to just take the leap to horizontal scaling.

### Our question, summed up

We hope we're going in the right direction, and we've done our homework, but we're not certain. We could certainly take a few tips on how to do this the right way.

## Thanks

I realize that this is a pretty long question, and making a well thought out answer will not be easy, but I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!!

Comment: maybe you can take advantage from [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) a good article [here](http://cjihrig.com/blog/scaling-node-js-applications/)

Comment: I'd like to know how this did over the years. It is an issue I am currently trying to address.

Comment: You may want to look at PM2. http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Answer (score 12):

Following my spontaneous thoughts on your case:

## Multicore usage

*node.js* can scale with multiple cores as well. How, you can read [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines) (*or just think about it: You have one thread/process running on one core, what do you need to use multiple cores? Multiple threads or multiple processes. Push work from main thread to other threads or processes and you are done*).

I personally would say it is childish to develop an application, which does not make use of multiple cores. If you make use of some background processes, ok, but if you until now only do work in the *node.js* main event loop, you should definitely invest some time to make the app scalable over cores.

Implementing something like IPC is not that easy by the way. You can do, but if your case is complicated maybe you are good to go with the cluster module. This is obviously not your favorite, but just because something is called "experimental" it does not mean it's trashy. Just give it a try, maybe you can even fix some bugs of the module on the way. It's most likely better to use some broadly used software for complex problems, than invent a new wheel.

You should also (if you do not already) think about (wise) usage of `nextTick` functionality. This allows the main event loop to pause some cpu intensive task and perform other work in the meanwhile. You can read about it [for example here](http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick).

## General thoughts on computations

You should definitely take a very close look at your algorithms of the game engine. You already noticed that this is your bottleneck right now and actually computations are the most critical part of mostly every game. Scaling does solve this problem in one way, but scaling introduces other problems. Also you cannot throw "scaling" as problem solver on everything and expect every problem to disappear.

Your best bet is to make your game code elegant and fast. Think about how to solve problems efficiently. If you cannot solve something in Javascript efficiently, but the problem can easily be extracted, why not write a little C component instead? This counts as a separate process as well, which reduces load on your main *node.js* event loop.

## Proxy?

Personally I do not see the advantage of the proxy level right now. You do not seem to expect large amount of users, you therefore won't need to solve problems like CDN solves or whatever... it's okay to think about it, but I would not invest much time there right now.

Technically there is a high chance your webserver software provides proxy functionality anyway. So it is ok to have it on the paper, but I would not plan with dedicated hardware right now.

## Epilogue

The rest seems more or less fine to me.

Comment: You've made a lot of interesting points, but I don't think this is what we're looking for. We do know that nodejs can make use of multiple core via the cluster module, but we don't want to use that, and we have our reasons (mainly that it would complicate our code further, and not yield any better results than having many single cored machines. We can either work on scaling horizontally now, or work with cluster, but we have to scale horizontally later anyways, so we should just do that now). You do have other great points, but they created more questions than answers. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the game, but take a look here: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/136/Horizontally-Scaling-Node.js-and-WebSockets-with-Redis

You did not mention anything to do with memory management.  As you know, `nodejs` doesn't share its memory with other processes, so an in-memory database is a must if you want to scale. (`Redis`, `Memcache`, etc). You need to setup a publisher & subscriber **event** on each node to accept incoming requests from `redis`. This way, you can scale up x nilo amount of servers (infront of your HAProxy) and utilize the data piped from `redis`.

There is also this `node` addon: http://blog.varunajayasiri.com/shared-memory-with-nodejs That lets you share memory between processes, but only works under Linux. This will help if you don't want to send data across local processes all the time or have to deal with `nodes` ipc api.

You can also fork child processes within `node` for a new v8 isolate to help with expensive cpu bound tasks. For example, players can kill monsters and obtain quite a bit of loot within my action rpg game. I have a child process called `LootGenerater`, and basically whenever a player kills a monster it sends the game `id`, `mob_id`, and `user_id` to the process via the default IPC api `.send`.  Once the child process receives it, it iterates over the large loot table and manages the items (stores to `redis`, or whatever) and pipes it back.

This helps free up the event loop greatly, and just one idea I can think of to help you scale. But most importantly you will want to use an in-memory database system and make sure your game code architecture is designed around whatever database system you use.  Don't make the mistake I did by now having to re-write everything :)

Hope this helps!

*Note: If you do decide to go with Memcache, you will need to utilize another pub/sub system.*