# Putting a Load on Node

Tags: node.js, multithreading, server, load, econnreset

We have a C# Web API server and a Node Express server. We make hundreds of requests from the C# server to a route on the Node server. The route on the Node server does intensive work and often doesn't return for 6-8 seconds.

Making hundreds of these requests simultaneously seems to cause the Node server to fail. Errors in the Node server output include either `socket hang up` or `ECONNRESET`. The error from the C# side says

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

This error occurs after processing an unpredictable number of the requests, which leads me to think it is simply overloading the server. Using a `Thread.Sleep(500)` on the C# side allows us to get through more requests, and fiddling with the wait there leads to more or less success, but thread sleeping is rarely if ever the right answer, and I think this case is no exception.

Are we simply putting too much stress on the Node server? Can this only be solved with Load Balancing or some form of clustering? If there is an another alternative, what might it look like?

One path I'm starting to explore is the [`node-toobusy`](https://github.com/lloyd/node-toobusy) module. If I return a 503 though, what should be the process in the following code? Should I `Thread.Sleep` and then re-submit the request?

Comment: It sounds like your node.js server is only running in one process, so load balancing isn't relevant yet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your node.js server is getting overloaded.

> The route on the Node server does intensive work and often doesn't return for 6-8 seconds.

This is a bad smell - if your node process is doing intense computation, it will halt the event loop until that computation is completed, and won't be able to handle any other requests. You should probably have it doing that computation in a worker process, which will run on another cpu core if available. `cluster` is the node builtin module that lets you do that, so I'll point you there.

> One path I'm starting to explore is the node-toobusy module. If I return a 503 though, what should be the process in the following code? Should I Thread.Sleep and then re-submit the request?

That depends on your application and your expected load. You may want to refresh once or twice if it's likely that things will cool down enough during that time, but for your API you probably just want to return a 503 in C# too - better to let the client know the server's too busy and let them make their own decision then to keep refreshing on its behalf.

Comment: `child_process.fork` is another way to spawn a worker node.js process