# How do I know or how do I run a Node.js server on different CPU cores?

Tags: node.js, express

Say my pc has a cpu with 2 cores, and my node.js application using express. How can i run this application on 1 core and this same application on the other core?

Comment: See the native cluster module

Answer (score 0):

`Nicovank` is right. You are interested in feature called `cluster`. In nodejs you getting number of cores by this code:

```
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
```

Please refer to this section of documentation: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster. The have great examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of an express server running in multiple cores using the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/cluster.html) module.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
//Get number of CPUs
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork one worker per core.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });

} else {
    //Worker code...

    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hello World!');
    });

    // Bind to a port
    app.listen(8080, () => {
        console.log(`[PID=${process.pid}] server started!`);
    });

}
```

There are some third party modules too:

- [Cluster2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster2)
- [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) (Node process manager that has [cluster mode](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/))
- StrongLoop - [strong-cluster-control](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-cluster-control)

You can also check:

[Node.js on multi-core machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387724/node-js-on-multi-core-machines?rq=1)