# How to make a long process run on the background without interrupting the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, background-process

I'm trying to make a function to create an ItemObj, and then import some requests related to it. The problem is that it uses an external API to bring a lot of data and that makes this step slower.

We want to leave the import on the background, while the UI can still be used.

```
public async Task<ItemObjDto> CreateItemObjAsync(ItemObjViewModel itemObjViewModel)
{
    var itemObj = CreateItemObj(itemObjViewModel);
    itemObjRepository.AddAsync(itemObj);
    await itemObjRepository.SaveAsync();

    // This import should happen in the background
    _requestAppService.ImportRequestsAsync(itemObj.Id);

    return _mapper.Map<ItemObjDto>(itemObj);
}
```

I've seen many posts with sugestions like using this:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    _requestAppService.ImportRequestsAsync(itemObj.Id);
});
```

But if I use it with the await it doesn't become asynchronous, and if I remove it, it becomes buggy, as it doesn't save correctly. And for some reason I can't even debug it properly, because it doesn't stops in a try/catch, neither around it, nor inside the _requestAppService.

I've also seen a waay more complex way to solve this in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63429262, but I had some trouble trying to make it call my appService with the import request...

I'm wondering if either of this solutions is what I'm looking for and if you can tell what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Maybe you should look up on Hangfire?

Comment: Are you looking for [fire-and-forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)?

Comment: It indeed looks like this is what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/nventive/BackgroundProcessing

Answer (score 0):

> if I use it with the await it doesn't become asynchronous, and if I
> remove it, it becomes buggy, as it doesn't save correctly. And for
> some reason I can't even debug it properly, because it doesn't stops
> in a try/catch, neither around it, nor inside the _requestAppService.
> I'm wondering if either of this solutions is what I'm looking for and
> if you can tell what I'm doing wrong

Well according to your scenario and description along with the shared code snippet I founded few inconsistent code which has downsides and can cause abnormal output or performence drawback.

You have used await while your task is `Task.Run(())` which is not recommended. Becuase, using [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#key-pieces-to-understand) inside a [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#key-pieces-to-understand) block can be inefficient and even harm your application's performance and responsiveness.

Most importantly, `Task.Run's` purpose is to offload non-UI work onto a background thread from the thread pool. So, adding [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#key-pieces-to-understand) inside Task.Run essentially blocks the background thread while waiting for another operation to complete.

Furthermore, when you await within Task.Run, you switch back and forth between the background thread and the calling thread repeatedly. This context switching adds overhead and can negatively impact your application's overall performance.

Therefore, you could modify you code as following:

```
public async Task<ItemObjDto> CreateItemObjAsync(ItemObjViewModel itemObjViewModel)
{
    var itemObj = CreateItemObj(itemObjViewModel);
    itemObjRepository.AddAsync(itemObj);
    await itemObjRepository.SaveAsync();

    
    _ = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await _requestAppService.ImportRequestsAsync(itemObj.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    });

    return _mapper.Map<ItemObjDto>(itemObj);
}
```

**Note:** Point to remember, this not the exact solution the problem you are having. But it would definitely improve your app performance sharply. In addition, you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to avoid deadlocks. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios#important-info-and-advice) for more insight.