# How can node use more than 100% CPU if it is single threaded?

Tags: node.js, performance, express, cpu-usage

I am running an express.js server. When I send some load the cpu usage spikes to over 140%.

I understand that since the system I am running the server on has 4 cores so it can go upto 400% as well.

My question is:

1. How can node.js application consume more than 100% despite being single threaded?
2. To improve the performance should I run the server in cluster mode? Currently a lot of requests are in http_request_waiting state.

Comment: I love to use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) to run my express APIs in cluster mode. Maybe it also fits your needs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2387724/2304737

Comment: @mr5 I checked that before posting. But that does not really answer how I have >100% cpu usage. Is it because node is spawning threads internally?

Comment: yeah. the javascript runs on a single thread, but node uses other threads for io, network, native modules.

Comment: There may be more than 1 thread running. You can run `ps -Tp <pid>` to show the threads of a process. Also top has a field `nTH` that will show the number of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the node is a single-threaded model that efficiently works on a single thread to serve the requests. But, it's underlying IO model is multi-threaded. There are two libuv components that act during the process one is event-pool and the other one is thread-pool and this thread pool is allocated with blocking operations like file reading, database queries, and IO operations.