# JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, foreach, node.js

I have a question regarding the native `Array.forEach` implementation of JavaScript: Does it behave asynchronously?
For example, if I call:

```
[many many elements].forEach(function () {lots of work to do})
```

Will this be non-blocking?

Comment: see also [Are all Node.js callback functions asynchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21884258/1048572)

Answer (score 446, accepted):

No, it is blocking. Have a look at the [specification of the algorithm](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18).

However a maybe easier to understand implementation is given on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill):

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach)
{
  Array.prototype.forEach = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
    }
  };
}
```

---

If you have to execute a lot of code for each element, you should consider to use a different approach:

```
function processArray(items, process) {
    var todo = items.concat();

    setTimeout(function() {
        process(todo.shift());
        if(todo.length > 0) {
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25);
        }
    }, 25);
}
```

and then call it with:

```
processArray([many many elements], function () {lots of work to do});
```

This would be non-blocking then. The example is taken from [*High Performance JavaScript*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X).

Another option might be [*web workers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!

Although I will try myself to find some alternative to that on the internet, anyone maybe who has an idea how to implement an async version of that function? would. for instance, a wrapping around setTimeout be enough?

Comment: If you're using Node.js, also consider using [process.nextTick](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/process.html#process.nextTick) instead of setTimeout

Comment: technically, forEach isn't "blocking", as the CPU never goes to sleep.  It's synchronous and CPU-bound, which can feel like "blocking" when you expect the node app to be responsive to events.

Comment: [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) would be probably a more appropriate solution here (in fact just seen someone posted that as an answer!).

Comment: todo.pop() [O(1)] in place of todo.shift() [O(N)] might be efficient. ref : (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22615787/3343029)

Comment: I trusted this answer, but it seems to be wrong in some cases. `forEach` does **not** block on `await` statements for instance and you should rather use a `for` loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962880/why-does-await-not-wait-and-why-does-sequelize-neither-respond-nor-error?noredirect=1#comment63373960_37962880

Comment: @Richard: of course. You can only use `await` inside `async` functions. But `forEach` doesn't know what async functions are. Keep in mind that async functions are just functions returning a promise. Would you expect `forEach` to handle a promise returned from the callback? `forEach` completely ignores the return value from the callback. It would only be able to handle an async callback if it was async itself.

Comment: @Richard in other words, `forEach` is synchronous, so you cannot pass an asynchronous callback to it. That never worked and `async/await` doesn't change that. Using `await` inside a `for` loop only works because the containing function is converted to a generator, which can be suspended until the promise is resolved (awaited). This answer isn't wrong, rather you seem to have wrong expectations of what async/await does.

Comment: @FelixKling I read the spec that you linked but could not find the part that speaks to `forEach` being synchronous of asynchronous. Where in the spec does it provide an answer?

Comment: @robertjewell: The algorithm itself is synchronous. It describes a loop where the callback is called in each iteration.

Comment: The link to the algorithm specification does not take you to the algorithm specification. It takes you to what looks to be a weird website.

Comment: @kipper_t: The spec is weird.

Comment: This article from the current maintainer of Mongoose has an excellent section on the use of async/await inside various looping constructs   https://thecodebarbarian.com/for-vs-for-each-vs-for-in-vs-for-of-in-javascript

Comment: @Richard thanks god you mentioned it. I was about to get crazy all over it

Comment: works perfectly in React Native with PusherJS. What is the role of `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 25)` ? I mean. does it have any effect on the blocking issue?

Comment: @Kasra: Yes. Instead of processing all elements at once, and potentially blocking the main thread, each element is processed in a separate job, given the browser time in between to do something else.

Answer (score 84):

If you need an asynchronous-friendly version of `Array.forEach` and similar, they're available in the Node.js 'async' module: http://github.com/caolan/async ...as a bonus this module also works in the browser.

```
async.each(openFiles, saveFile, function(err){
    // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

Comment: If you need to ensure that the async opeartion is run for **only one item at a time (in the order of the collection)**, you must use `eachSeries` instead.

Comment: @JohnKennedy I've seen you before!

Answer (score 18):

There is a common pattern for doing a really heavy computation in Node that may be applicable to you...

Node is single-threaded (as a deliberate design choice, see [What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js/6782438#6782438)); this means that it can only utilize a single core.  Modern boxes have 8, 16, or even more cores, so this could leave 90+% of the machine idle.  The common pattern for a REST service is to fire up one node process per core, and put these behind a local load balancer like http://nginx.org/.

***Forking a child*** - 
For what you are trying to do, there is another common pattern, forking off a child process to do the heavy lifting.  The upside is that the child process can do heavy computation in the background while your parent process is responsive to other events.  The catch is that you can't / shouldn't share memory with this child process (not without a LOT of contortions and some native code); you have to pass messages.  This will work beautifully if the size of your input and output data is small compared to the computation that must be performed.  You can even fire up a child node.js process and use the same code you were using previously.

For example:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
function run_in_child(array, cb) {
    var process = child_process.exec('node libfn.js', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        var output = JSON.parse(stdout);
        cb(err, output);
    });
    process.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(array), 'utf8');
    process.stdin.end();
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear... Node isn't single threaded, but the execution of your JavaScript is.  IO and what not runs on separate threads.

Comment: @Brad - maybe.  that's implementation dependent.  With appropriate kernel support, the interface between Node and the kernel can be event-based - kqueue (mac), epoll (linux), IO completion ports (windows).  As a fallback, a pool of threads also works.  Your basic point is right though.  The low-level Node implementation might have multiple threads.  But they will NEVER directly expose them to JS userland as that would break the entire language model.

Comment: Correct, I'm just clarifying because the concept has confused many.

Comment: It's misleading to say that Node.js is single-threaded. There's a lot of technicalities here. The Javascript interpreter is single-threaded, but the IO subsystem (which is part of node) is multi-threaded. Async/await (aka promises) invokes parallel threads. Additionally, worker threads allow multiple Javascript threads to run in parallel.

Answer (score 7):

`Array.forEach` is meant for computing stuff not waiting, and there is nothing to be gained making computations asynchronous in an event loop (webworkers add multiprocessing, if you need multi-core computation). If you want to wait for multiple tasks to end, use a counter, which you can wrap in a semaphore class.

Answer (score 5):

Edit 2018-10-11:
It looks like there is a good chance the standard described below may not go through, consider [pipelineing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator) as an alternative (does not behave exactly the same but methods could be implemented in a similar manor).

This is exactly why I am excited about es7, in future you will be able to do something like the code below (some of the specs are not complete so use with caution, I will try to keep this up to date). But basically using the new :: bind operator, you will be able to run a method on an object as if the object's prototype contains the method. eg [Object]::[Method] where normally you would call [Object].[ObjectsMethod]

Note to do this today (24-July-16) and have it work in all browsers you will need to transpile your code for the following functionality:**Import / Export**, **Arrow functions**, **Promises**, **Async / Await** and most importantly **function bind**. The code below could be modfied to use only function bind if nessesary, all this functionality is neatly available today by using [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

YourCode.js (where '*lots of work to do*' must simply return a promise, resolving it when the asynchronous work is done.)

```
import { asyncForEach } from './ArrayExtensions.js';

await [many many elements]::asyncForEach(() => lots of work to do);
```

ArrayExtensions.js

```
export function asyncForEach(callback)
{
    return Promise.resolve(this).then(async (ar) =>
    {
        for(let i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
        {
            await callback.call(ar, ar[i], i, ar);
        }
    });
};

export function asyncMap(callback)
{
    return Promise.resolve(this).then(async (ar) =>
    {
        const out = [];
        for(let i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
        {
            out[i] = await callback.call(ar, ar[i], i, ar);
        }
        return out;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

These code snippet will give you better understanding of forEach and forOf comparison.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
async function forEachTest() {
    console.log('########### Testing forEach ################ ')
    console.log('start of forEachTest func')
    let a = [1, 2, 3]
    await a.forEach(async (v) => {
        console.log('start of forEach: ', v)
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, v * 1000))
        console.log('end of forEach: ', v)
    })
    console.log('end of forEachTest func')
}
forEachTest()


async function forOfTest() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000)) //just see console in proper way
    console.log('\n\n########### Testing forOf ################ ')
    console.log('start of forOfTest func')
    let a = [1, 2, 3]
    for (const v of a) {
        console.log('start of forOf: ', v)
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, v * 1000))
        console.log('end of forOf: ', v)
    }
    console.log('end of forOfTest func')
}
forOfTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a short asynchronous function to use without requiring third party libs

```
Array.prototype.each = function (iterator, callback) {
    var iterate = function () {
            pointer++;
            if (pointer >= this.length) {
                callback();
                return;
            }
            iterator.call(iterator, this[pointer], iterate, pointer);
    }.bind(this),
        pointer = -1;
    iterate(this);
};
```

Comment: How is this asynchronous? AFAIK #call will execute immediately?

Comment: Of course immediately, but you have callback function to know when all iterations be completed. Here "iterator" argument is a node-style async function with callback. It's similar to async.each method

Comment: I don't see how this is async. call or apply are synchronous. Having a callback doesn't make it async

Comment: in javascript when people say async, they mean that the code execution does not block the main event loop (aka, it does not make the proccess stuck at one line of code).  just putting a callback does not make code async, it has to utilize some form of event loop releasing such as a setTimeout, or setInterval.   since durning the time you wait for those, other code can run without interruptions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package on npm for easy [asynchronous for each loops](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forEachAsync).

```
var forEachAsync = require('futures').forEachAsync;

// waits for one request to finish before beginning the next 
forEachAsync(['dogs', 'cats', 'octocats'], function (next, element, index, array) {
  getPics(element, next);
  // then after all of the elements have been handled 
  // the final callback fires to let you know it's all done 
  }).then(function () {
    console.log('All requests have finished');
});
```

Also another variation [forAllAsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forallasync)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to code even the solution like this for example :

```
 var loop = function(i, data, callback) {
    if (i < data.length) {
        //TODO("SELECT * FROM stackoverflowUsers;", function(res) {
            //data[i].meta = res;
            console.log(i, data[i].title);
            return loop(i+1, data, errors, callback);
        //});
    } else {
       return callback(data);
    }
};

loop(0, [{"title": "hello"}, {"title": "world"}], function(data) {
    console.log("DONE\n"+data);
});
```

On the other hand, it is much slower than a "for".

Otherwise, the excellent Async library can do this: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Answer (score -1):

Here is a small example you can run to test it:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].forEach(function(n){
    var sum = 0;
    console.log('Start for:' + n);
    for (var i = 0; i < ( 10 - n) * 100000000; i++)
        sum++;

    console.log('Ended for:' + n, sum);
});
```

It will produce something like this(if it takes too less/much time, increase/decrease the number of iterations):

```
(index):48 Start for:1
(index):52 Ended for:1 900000000
(index):48 Start for:2
(index):52 Ended for:2 800000000
(index):48 Start for:3
(index):52 Ended for:3 700000000
(index):48 Start for:4
(index):52 Ended for:4 600000000
(index):48 Start for:5
(index):52 Ended for:5 500000000
(index):48 Start for:6
(index):52 Ended for:6 400000000
(index):48 Start for:7
(index):52 Ended for:7 300000000
(index):48 Start for:8
(index):52 Ended for:8 200000000
(index):48 Start for:9
(index):52 Ended for:9 100000000
(index):45 [Violation] 'load' handler took 7285ms
```

Comment: This will happen even if you will write async.foreach or any other parallel method. Because as for loop is not an IO process Nodejs will always do it synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

Although Array.forEach is not asynchronous, you can get asynchronous "end result". Example below:

```js
function delayFunction(x) {
    return new Promise(
        (resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(x), 1000)
    );
}

[1, 2, 3].forEach(async(x) => {
    console.log(x);
    console.log(await delayFunction(x));
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Use **Promise.each** of [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html) library.

```
Promise.each(
Iterable<any>|Promise<Iterable<any>> input,
function(any item, int index, int length) iterator
) -> Promise
```

This method iterates over an array, or a promise of an array, which contains promises (or a mix of promises and values) with the given **iterator** function with the signature **(value, index, length)** where the **value** is the resolved value of a respective promise in the input array. **Iteration happens serially.** If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited before continuing with next iteration. If any promise in the input array is rejected, then the returned promise is rejected as well.

If all of the iterations resolve successfully, **Promise.each** **resolves to the original array unmodified**. However, if one iteration rejects or errors, **Promise.each** ceases execution immediately and does not process any further iterations. The error or rejected value is returned in this case instead of the original array.

This method is meant to be used for side effects.

```
var fileNames = ["1.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt"];

Promise.each(fileNames, function(fileName) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(fileName).then(function(val){
        // do stuff with 'val' here.  
    });
}).then(function() {
console.log("done");
});
```