# ES5: Returning parent function once all items have called back with a forEach

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, for-loop, ecmascript-5

I'm looking at using ES5's new [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). I believe the callbacks for each item should execute in parallel. I'd like a function to return once all values have processed.

```
// I'd like to make parent_function return a new array with the changed items.
function parent_function(array_of_things) {
    new_array = []
    array_of_things.forEach( function(thing) {
        new_array.push('New '+thing)
        if ( new_array.length === array_of_things.length ) {
            // OK we've processed all the items. How do I make parent_function return the completed new_array? 
            return new_array
        }
    })
}
```

**I suspect that this may be the wrong approach**: because the parent_function may finish before every callback has been fired. In this case, **firing a custom event** (that's handled by whatever needs the data produced after we've processed all the items) may be the best approach. However I didn't find any mention of that in the MDC docs.

But I'm fairly new to JS and would love some peer review to confirm!

**Edit: Looks like forEach() is synchronous after all.** I was logging the resulting array afterwards and seeing inconsistent results - sometimes two items, sometimes four, etc, which made me think it was async. If you're reading this and having similar behaviour, I suggest you read this [item about issues in Chrome's array logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forEach() call is synchronous, you can just return the new Array when the forEach() is finished:

```
function parent_function(array_of_things) {
  var new_array = [];
  array_of_things.forEach(function(thing) {
    new_array.push('New '+thing);
  });
  return new_array;
}
```

Comment: Hehe thanks. I think I just assumed async due to some other odd behaviour. http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.18 mentions the sync behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, all these iterator functions are synchronous. That means, the callbacks are executed one after the other each with the next item, then in the end `forEach()` returns (and returns undefined).

If you want a `new_array` with the results of each callback invokation, you'd have a look at [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Thanks - I've found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-nodejs-is-array-foreach-asynchronous which has a reference for it being syncronous to confirm your answer. Is map() the **only** solution to get a new_array with all the modified items in it?

Comment: What other solution would you seek for? Of course you can always build a new array manually while iterating (elegant solution uses [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)).