# How to know when finished

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Im pretty new to node.js, so i'm wondering how to know when all elements are processed in lets say:

```
["one", "two", "three"].forEach(function(item){
    processItem(item, function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

...now if i want to do something that can only be done when all items are processed, how would i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async). Simple example: The

```
async.map(['one','two','three'], processItem, function(err, results){
    // results[0] -> processItem('one');
    // results[1] -> processItem('two');
    // results[2] -> processItem('three');
});
```

The callback function of async.map will when all items are processed. However, in processItem you should be careful, processItem should be something like this:

```
processItem(item, callback){
   // database call or something:
   db.call(myquery, function(){
       callback(); // Call when async event is complete!
   });
}
```

Comment: Interesting, how about when it is on several levels. If processItem also calls a async function like saving to a database

Comment: My example just illustrates that, this module is meant to be used by asnychronous function calls, like database ops. If it is sequential, you won't use that.

Comment: sorry, i read the post on an iPad and missed the latter part. Thanks, that looks like the right solution

Comment: callback() is called after each processItem() completes.  How do you know when *all* items in map have been processed?  It is hard to understand how **async module** works.

Answer (score 1):

forEach is blocking, see this post:

[JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-nodejs-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)

so to call a function when all items are done processing, it can be done inline:

```
["one", "two", "three"].forEach(function(item){
    processItem(item, function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
console.log('finished');
```

if there is a high io-bound load for each item to be processed, then take a look at the module Mustafa recommends.  there is also a pattern referenced in the post linked above.

Comment: Yes, i know that forEach is, but processItem is not.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit other answers are correct, since node.js supports ES6 henceforth, in my opinion using built-in `Promise` library will be more stable and tidy.

You don't even need to require something, Ecma took the *Promises/A+* library and implemented it to the native Javascript.

```
Promise.all(["one", "two","three"].map(processItem))
  .then(function (results) {
    //  here we got the results in the same order of array
} .catch(function (err) {
    //  do something with error if your function throws
}
```

As Javascript is a adequately problematic language (dynamic typing, asynchronous flow) when it comes to debugging, sticking with `promise`s instead of callbacks will save your time at the end.