# Can a controller forEach "res.json(item)" when using sockets.io?

Tags: sails.js

I want my controller to send over multiple items as I find them. Can I call "`res.json(item)`" multiple times? I did a quick test and it seams to work a bit.

Background: I have a **"collection"** model that holds, among other things, an array of ids (~30). 
ForEach Id, I find the "ItemModel" with that id and send it to the backbonejs client to add it to a displayed list.

Since forEach is asynchronous, and the model.find method required a callback anyway I thought it would be wise to "`res.json(item)`" for each item, sending back ~30 frames.

**The problem** arises on the backbone.js side of things as **~30 socket frames** are shown on chrome's network debug, but backbone only calls a single renderAdd event.

My renderAdd function works perfectly for a single addition, only appends, and has been tested by viewing another list of items)

**In general**, am I taking the correct approach or do I have a fundamentally flawed approach?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [QAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-nodejs-is-array-foreach-asynchronous) foreach is blocking, but the sync() method of BB.js is asynchronous. You can also try to use [_.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) of Undescore.js, which is a same but have a nicer syntax.

```
_.each([1, 2, 3], alert);
```

The real solution to your problem is to add multiple models at once:

```
ships.add([
  {name: "Flying Dutchman"},
  {name: "Black Pearl"}
]);
```