# How to identify Loop is completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I want to minimize following code. Working in **node js**

```
var each = 0;
var final = {};
// myLoop have some array values;
myLoop.forEach(function(row) {

    //data retrive from db
    db.query('SELECT * FROM test where type=?',[row.type], function(err, result) {
        final[each] = result;
        each++;
        if (each == myLoop.length) {
           return final;
        }
    });

});
```

Above code working fine, but trying to avoid **if (each == myLoop.length)** condition.
Is anything available to identify the loop is completed?

Is possible something like below:

```
myLoop.forEach(function(row) {
    //do needs
}).done({
    return final;
});
```

Comment: Is the data retrieval asynchronous?

Comment: @TravisJ inside forEach im retrieving data from database.

Comment: UM, if the Ajax code is asynchronous, your logic is flawed in more that one way.

Comment: @suresh.g - I mean, the classical approach would be to just return final once the loop runs *outside* of the forEach so that it is fully populated. The only reason that wouldn't work is if the db call was async hence my question.

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry, im confused the word asynchronous, and i updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your need should cooperate with DB side.

Even the [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L118) determines if all callbacks are completed through *counting*

If you use MongoDB with node driver,
you can try to issue your queries in [`aggregation`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/anintroductionto1_4_and_2_6.html#aggregation-cursors)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Caolan's Async library (or you can take a look how it is done in this lib) - https://github.com/caolan/async#each

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names 

async.each(openFiles, function( file, callback) {

  // Perform operation on file here.
  console.log('Processing file ' + file);

  if( file.length > 32 ) {
    console.log('This file name is too long');
    callback('File name too long');
  } else {
    // Do work to process file here
    console.log('File processed');
    callback();
  }
}, function(err){
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in the short term, you could make use of forEach's index:

```
var final = {};
// myLoop have some array values;
myLoop.forEach( function( row, index ) {
    //data retrive from db
    final[ index ] = row;
    if (index === myLoop.length) {
        return final;
    }
});
```

And why are you returning 'final'? Were you hoping to do something like trigger an event instead?

Comment: Sorry, Actually i did same as you provided. But i mentioned what im expecting

Comment: My need is to avoid **if (index === myLoop.length) {**

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the callback function. It will get executed only when everything is completed.

```
 // Call the function
 loopTheArray(myLoop,function(final){
    //Do whatever you want with final
 });

function loopTheArray(myLoop,callback){
    var final = {},each=0;
    myLoop.forEach(function(row) {
        //data retrive from db
        final[each] = row;
    });
    callback(final);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78sg9agb/)

Comment: Here, my problem is the callback(final) function will be execute before the myLoop is fully completed

Comment: @suresh.g: This cannot be. added a fiddle to demonstrate how its working. It will work since forEach is blocking. For reference see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-nodejs-is-array-foreach-asynchronous

Comment: Actually im having database query inside loop. so, definitely the callback(final) will be execute before myLoop complete