# Async each vs forEach js

Tags: javascript, async.js

Can someone explain me the different between this two:

```
async.each(items, function (item, callback) {
    // Do something
});
```

OR :

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
 // Do something
)};
```

Comment: synchronized vs unsynchronized (asynchronous)

Comment: The first will continue execution of any script after `.each()`, while the loop is still running.  The second will complete the loop before any further script is executed.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5050317/6103920) and the [ECMA specification for forEach](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.18)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### async.each

is non blocking (asynchronous), means the execution of your script goes on while it's running. It's also running parallel, means that multiple items are processed at the same time. It's a method provided by an external library, I guess [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each). It's not a native Javascript feature and not added to `Array.prototype`, thus you can't write `myArray.each`.

### Array.forEach

is blocking (synchronous), means the execution of your script waits till it's finished. It's running serial, means that each item is processed after the former item has been processed. `forEach` is a native Javascript function ([spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.18)) & defined on the `Array.proptotype`, thus you can simply write `myArray.forEach` instead of `Array.forEach(myArray)`. If you, for example, push to an array in your `forEach`loop, then you can access the pushed values in the lines after the `forEach` call.

Comment: also worth noting that `async.each` executes in parallel. `async.eachSeries` is available if needed.