# synchronous and asynchronous loops in javascript

Tags: javascript

Are loops synchronous or asynchronous in JavaScript? (for, while, etc)

Supposing I have:

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
    // A (nested stuff...)
}

// B ...
```

Using `for` the execution of `B` will start before `A` sometimes... (so asynchronous)

Is there a way to use statements in a synchronous way?

Comment: _"Using `for` the execution of `B` will start before `A` sometimes"_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 it can be anything, more nested statements, ajax, logic etc etc

Comment: `for` loop is synchronous. `B` should not be executed before `for` loop completes. Can you demonstrate case of `B` "somtimes" starting execution before `for` loop completes?  Are there asynchronous operations within `for` loop which may not be called until some time in future, after `B` has started execution?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: what will appear to happen is that callbacks registered for functions doing asynchronous I/O - for example - are called after B has executed.
However, the code above runs sequentially and at a later point your callbacks are being called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)

Comment: loops are synchronous until you do some async operations inside, then it's async.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The for loop runs immediately to completion while all your asynchronous operations are started.

Well, here we have some nested loops. Notice, "BBB" always fires after.

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
   for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
     for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
       console.log("AA")
     }
   }
}

console.log('BBB')
```

now, look at this

```
for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
   setTimeout(function() {console.log("AA")}, 2000)
}

console.log('BBB')
```

This is because of something called the "event loop". And the fact that with that setTimeout we are simulating an async operation. It could be an ajax call or some other async process.

Check this out: http://latentflip.com/loupe

This will really help you understand these sorts of async/sync loop topics.

updated to show how promises might work here (given comments below):

```
var stringValues = ['yeah', 'noooo', 'rush', 'RP'];
var P = function(val, idx){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(val), 1000 * idx));
};


// We now have an array of promises waiting to be resolved.
// The Promise.all basically will resolve once ALL promises are 
// resolved. Keep in mind, that if at any time something rejects
// it stops

// we iterator over our stringValues array mapping over the P function, 
// passing in the value of our array.
var results = Promise.all(stringValues.map(P));

// once all are resolved, the ".then" now fires. It is here we would do 
results.then(data => 
    console.log(data) //["yeah", "noooo", "rush", "RP"]
);
```

let me know if I am not clear enough.

Comment: Should I create something like a promise to resolve after the interval ?

Comment: well, not in your original question because given a standard loop - it will always run to completion before "BBB" happens. BUT, my guess is that you have some sort async operation that "might take some time" and then "BBB" comes before, is that correct?

Comment: this is great. But what to do if I want to break out of the loop?

Comment: darnit this isn't a "synchronous" type loop - all the timeouts are being fired off at the same time; it's just the wait that's being staggered by `1000 * idx`

Comment: you could add a break; statement. Instead of using let i, use let a,b,c , a for first loop, b for second etc.. and then for example, in the inner loop type: if (a >= 1) break;, and you'll see that the other parts of the loops do not run. Is that what you mean?

Comment: all console.log are being fired at the same time

Comment: correct, if you want to verify the closure worked, just add the i in the console log.  If you wanted the setTimeouts to fire every two seconds, just do as suggested above and do 2000 * i

Answer (score 24):

If you place asynchronous loops inside a `for...loop` and want to stop the loop until each operation ends, you must use the `async/await` syntax like this.

```
async function foo() {
    var array = [/* some data that will be used async*/]

    //This loop will wait for each next() to pass the next iteration
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        await new Promise(next=> {
            someAsyncTask(array[i], function(err, data){
                /*.... code here and when you finish...*/
                next()
            })
        })        
    }
}

foo().then(() => { /*After foo execution*/ })
```

Comment: Any code after foo() will run before `someAsyncTask` inside the loop.

Comment: @tiomno yeah that's because foo is a Promise, just put that code in `foo().then(() => { /*Your code here*/ })`

Comment: Thank you! This is a true asynchronous loop, because each run is waiting for the previous one before firing. I'm able to 'skip' out when a condition is met by simply skipping the `someAsyncTask()` function call but still executing `next()` so that the `then..` part is done regardless. This should be the chosen answer.

Comment: In this approch, If I want to add some delay too with my `someAsyncTask`.. what is the best way to do this?

Comment: @GauravAgrawal await new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(), 3000))

Answer (score 9):

use **for** **of**

```
for(let item of items) {
    await yourASyncFunctions(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, your statement about **"*Using for the execution of B will start before A sometimes... (so asynchronous)*"** is wrong.

The loop function (like `while`, `for`, `.forEach` or `.map`) in *Javascript* will be run *synchronously* (*blocking*), whether you run it in a *Browser* or *Runtime Environment* like *NodeJS*. We can prove it by running the code below (*maybe the process will take a few seconds*):

```js
let counter1 = 0
let counter2 = 0
let counter3 = 0

console.log("Start iteration")
console.time("Time required")

// First heavy iteration
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  counter1 += 1

  // Second heavy iteration
  for (let i2 = 0; i2 < 1000; i2++) {
    counter2 += 1

    // Third heavy iteration
    for (let i3 = 0; i3 < 1000; i3++) {
      counter3 += 1
    }
  }
}

console.log("Iteration was successful")
console.timeEnd("Time required")
console.log('The value of `counter1` is: ' + counter1)
console.log('The value of `counter2` is: ' + counter2)
console.log('The value of `counter3` is: ' + counter3)
```

> And then what kind of looping causes your code to run *asynchronously* (*non blocking*)?

The answer is:

> The code that is placed inside the `Promise` *callback* or the `function` with the `async` keyword or some native functions with *callback* (not all) like `setTimeout`, `setInterval` and *etc* will be run *asynchronously*.

Example:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('A')
})

console.log('B')
```

> In code, `setTimeout` function is declared first. However, the output of the code shows that the `console.log('B')` function run earlier than the `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 4):

```
for(const elment of arrayElements) {
            await yourFunc(elment)
            await yourOtherFunc('somePatameter')
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.