# aynchronous forEach loop returning an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am struggling with asynchronous loop, here is what I tried:

```
let array = [];      
  raw.forEach(async element => {
      var elt = new Elt(raw);
      elt.options = await this.getOptions(raw["id"]);
      array.push(elt);
  });
  return array; // this is empty...
```

How can I "wait for it to be finished" so that the array isn't empty?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `.map` or `.reduce` and `Promise.all` instead.  `.forEach` won't wait.

Comment: You might want to check this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173350/synchronous-and-asynchronous-loops-in-javascript

Comment: Your code seems to be wrong. Why is it using `raw["id"]`? Do you mean `element.id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem: The output array is empty because you use it *before* any of promises is executes. You have to `await` all promises before using the array.

The second problem: Promises can execute and therefore `push` items in (pseudo-)random order. Your output array can get shuffled.

The solution is (1) `await` all promises and (2) keep order of them (using `Array.prototype.map`):

```js
async function foo(input) {
    let output = await Promise.all(input.map(async element => {
        return element * 2;
    }));

    return output;
}

// Call it
let input = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, ]; // This is your input array
foo(input).then(output => console.log(output));
```

The [`Promises.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is `async` function that takes array of promises and returns array of their results.

`Array.prototype.map` executes function for each item of the array.

More information:

- [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) and [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) about Promises on MDN
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and Promise.all for your scenario

```
  const promises = raw.map(async element => {
    var elt = new Elt(element )
    elt.options = await this.getOptions(element ["id"])
    return elt
  })
  
  const yourArray = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Answer (score 1):

First await the completion of the async fetching of all of the options using `map` and `Promise.all`, and then map those IDs to a list of elements, something like this:

```
const options = await Promise.all(raw.map(r => this.getOptions(r.id)));

const elements = options.map(option => {
    const elt = new Elt();
    elt.options = option;
    return elt;
});
```