# Javascript Promise prematurely resolving

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise

I have a function that returns a Promise, that accesses the database and pulls a few lines out, assigning them to a Javascript variable.

The issue is that my '.then' clause is being triggered even though I know the Promise hasn't resolved:

```
app.post("/api/hashtag", function (req, res) {

FindPopularRumours().then(function (resolveVar) {
    console.log(resolveVar);
    console.log();
    res.send(resolveVar);
}).catch(function () {
    console.log("DB Error!");
    res.send("DB Error!");
});
});
```

And the Promise function:

```
function FindPopularRumours() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var hashtags = [];
    var dbPromise;

    db.collection(HASHTAGS).find().forEach(function (doc) {
        hashtags.push(doc.hashtag);
        console.log(hashtags);
    });
    resolve(hashtags);
});
}
```

The result output is:

> [ ]
>
> ['#test1']
>
> ['#test1', '#test2']
>
> ['#test1', '#test2', '#test3']

As you can see, the first line ('[ ]') should ONLY be executed AFTER the hashtags have been output. But for some reason my code seems to think the Promise has been resolved before it actually has.

## **EDIT1**

As per Ankit's suggestion, I have amended my function to:

```
function FindPopularRumours() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var hashtags = [];

    db.collection(HASHTAGS).find({}, function (err, doc) {
        if (!err) {
            doc.forEach(function (arg) {
                hashtags.push(arg.hashtag);
                console.log(hashtags);
            });
            resolve(hashtags);
        } else {
            return reject(err);
        }
    });
});
}
```

This still returns the same output response as before (e.g the 'then' clause is running before the promise itself).

My POST function is still the same as before.

Comment: Of course, because you indeed resolve promise before it loaded data. `db.collection(HASHTAGS).find()` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db.collection.find()` function is async, so you have to resolve the promise **inside** the callback for that, something like

```
function FindPopularRumours() {
    return db.collection(HASHTAGS).find().toArray().then( (items) => {
        return items.map( doc => doc.hashtag);
    });
}
```

takes advantage of the Mongo `toArray()` method, that returns a promise directly

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. After changing to your suggestion, the console output is now:
`Promise { <pending> }`
This is when i do:
`console.log(FindPopularRumours());`

I've not seen this pending message before, but I guess the db find is not being resolved somehow..?

Comment: Uh, that's because that function is returning a **promise**, were'nt you suppose to be doing `FindPopularRumours().then(function (resolveVar) {...`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `db.collection(HASHTAGS).find()` is an asynchronous call. So, your promise is resolved before database query returns. To solve this problem, you need to re-write your database query as follows:

```
function FindPopularRumours() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       var hashtags = [];
       var dbPromise;

       db.collection(HASHTAGS).find({}, function(err, doc){
           if(!err){
              doc.forEach(function (arg) {
                  hashtags.push(arg.hashtag);
                  console.log(hashtags);
              });
              resolve(hashtags);
           }else{
               return reject(err);
           }
       });
   });
}
```

Hope the answer helps you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I have amended my code to match yours, and still have the same issue. I guess it's still executing resolve() too fast (as you mentioned, because it is async). I tried making an array of promises, and my response to be triggered only when all the promises are fulfilled, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: That's really strange! I don't see why it won't work. Can you update your question and post your amended code?

Comment: `doc.forEach` is asynchronous in nature hence the `resolve(hashtags)` gets executed first. To work around this use `doc.toArray` and call resolve inside the callback of toArray.

Comment: Thanks for both your help (@nurulnabi too). toArray works. I have amended the original post to show solution.

Comment: @nurulnabi forEach() is a blocking call. You can check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous) to verify it. I am not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: though forEach may be blocking but in case of mongodb cursor it doesn't work like that.