# returning array after finish reading from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push all values that satisfy a certain condition to an array then return this array. Here's my code

```
exports.getNearbyPosts = function (myLat, myLng){
  var query = firebase.database().ref("posts/").orderByKey();
  var listOfItems = [];
  query.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var dist = getDistanceBetweenCoord(childData.lat, childData.lng, myLat, myLng);
        if(dist < 10239820938502){
          listOfItems.push(childSnapshot);
        }
    });
  });

  return listOfItems;
}
```

However since forEach is asynchronous, and it seems like I cannot use a callback on forEach, the listOfItems I return would just be an empty array. I have also tried ".then", but it would only allow me to do more stuff inside ".then" and I would like to return this array as a variable to other parts of the code. How can I return the correct array after forEach has been executed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the `forEach` that is async ([JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)), it's the `query.once("value")`. You can solve this problem in a variety of ways. With callbacks, promises, or await/async.

I suggest reading this very informative answer that covers much more with better examples: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

## With callbacks

The idea here is to provide a function that can be called with the result once the asynchronous work is done, but after our work in `forEach` is complete.

```js
exports.getNearbyPosts = function (myLat, myLng, callback){
  var query = firebase.database().ref("posts/").orderByKey();
  var listOfItems = [];
  query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      var dist = getDistanceBetweenCoord(childData.lat, childData.lng, myLat, myLng);
      if(dist < 10239820938502){
        listOfItems.push(childSnapshot);
      }
    });
    callback(listOfItems)
  });
}

getNearbyPosts(0, 0, (result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

## With promises (ES2016)

Promises are another way to handle asynchronous code. I suggest reading about them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises. It will explain them far better than I could.

Here is your code using promises:

```js
exports.getNearbyPosts = function (myLat, myLng){
  var query = firebase.database().ref("posts/").orderByKey();
  var listOfItems = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        var dist = getDistanceBetweenCoord(childData.lat, childData.lng, myLat, myLng);
        if(dist < 10239820938502){
          listOfItems.push(childSnapshot);
        }
      });
      resolve(listOfItems);
    });
  });
}

getNearbyPosts(0, 0).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

This can actually be simplified further as it appears `query.once` returns a promise itself. We can simply return the promise provided to us by `query.once` which will fire once after the `.then` of your internal function. We can chain them together like so.

```js
exports.getNearbyPosts = function (myLat, myLng){
  var query = firebase.database().ref("posts/").orderByKey();
  var listOfItems = [];
  
  // We return the promise created by query.once
  return query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  
    // our inital .then will do some data filtering
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      var key = childSnapshot.key;
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      var dist = getDistanceBetweenCoord(childData.lat, childData.lng, myLat, myLng);
      if(dist < 10239820938502){
        listOfItems.push(childSnapshot);
      }
    });
    
    // We return here to continue the chain. The next .then that picks this up will have this result
    return listOfItems;
  });
}

// Our last promise resolution in the chain, containing listOfItems
getNearbyPosts(0, 0).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Great answer Devan! Just as an fyi. `Snapshot` is not exactly an `Array`, but `Snapshot.forEach()` is indeed also synchronous.

Comment: Ah, so it isn't! https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot. Good to know, thanks for the info.