# statement after for loop runs before for loop is done running

Tags: javascript, node.js

why is objlist being resolved before loop has completed. Since the for loop is sync, I expected resolve to be run after my for loop has completed, but list with empty object is being resolved.

```
 function myFunction(path,files){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            let objlist=[];
            files.forEach(function(file,index){
                console.log(file)
                objlist[index]={};
                fs.stat(path + '\\' + file, function(err,stats){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err.code)
                        console.log(err)
                        throw err;
                    }
                    if(stats.isDirectory()){
                        objlist[index].file = 'folder'
                    }
                    else if(stats.isFile()){
                        objlist[index].file = 'file'
                    }
                    objlist[index].name = file
                    console.log(objlist[index].name) //gives correct output
                    objlist[index].size = stats.size
                });
            })
            console.log(objlist); //gives list of empty objects
            resolve(objlist);

        });
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just use the form `for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ )` ?

Comment: @JeffBreadner I used that too but that didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use await you can either use Promise.all or a counter to know when all `fs.stat` has resolved:

Using only `Promise.all`:

```
 function myFunction(path,files){
    return Promise.all(files.map(function(file,index){
            console.log(file)
            var obj = {};
            fs.stat(path + '\\' + file, function(err,stats){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err.code)
                    console.log(err)
                    throw err;
                }
                if(stats.isDirectory()){
                    obj.file = 'folder'
                }
                else if(stats.isFile()){
                    obj.file = 'file'
                }
                obj.name = file
                console.log(objlist[index].name) //gives correct output
                obj.size = stats.size
                return obj;
            });
        }))
    .then(objList => {
        console.log(objlist); //gives list of empty objects
        resolve(objlist);
    });
}
```

Or using a counter:

```
 function myFunction(path,files){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let objlist=[];
        var counter = files.length;
        files.forEach(function(file,index){
            console.log(file)
            objlist[index]={};
            fs.stat(path + '\\' + file, function(err,stats){
                counter--;
                if(err){
                    console.log(err.code)
                    console.log(err)
                    throw err;
                }
                if(stats.isDirectory()){
                    objlist[index].file = 'folder'
                }
                else if(stats.isFile()){
                    objlist[index].file = 'file'
                }
                objlist[index].name = file
                console.log(objlist[index].name) //gives correct output
                objlist[index].size = stats.size
                if(counter == 0) {
                    console.log(objlist); //gives list of empty objects
                    resolve(objlist);
                }
            });
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` expects a function and executes it synchronously (see [JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)). `fs.stat` is async so there's no guarantee that all iterations will finish before calling `resolve(objlist)`.

Here's a suggestion:

```
const objlist = await Promise.all(files.map(async file => {
  // return a promise
}))
resolve(objlist)
```

I like this article on promises and ES6 for a primer: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Edited thanks to feedback from https://stackoverflow.com/users/6351322/guijob

Comment: Whoops, big time brain fart. Thanks @guijob. Does my edit make sense?

Comment: In fact, forEach just expects a function and will execute it synchronously for each element of array, but if this function has async operations then you have to handle their responses manually.

Comment: it says unexpected identifier Promise.all

Comment: You need to be using ES6 and have this inside an `async` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `fs.stat` call is not synchronous because it uses a callback.  Your `forEach` loop will launch all of the `fs.stat` processes and then continue, but it will not (nor can you make it) wait for all of the callbacks to be called before it carries on.

I think an approach like the one below will work.  `fs-extra` is a good promisified version of `fs`, and `bluebird` is a promise library that extends standard Promises.  I'm not sure if that is necessary, you didn't say which version of Node you're using; I'm using it to get access to the `each` method.  Try it without Bluebird, it might work.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
global.Promise = Promise;


function myFunction(path,files){
  return Promise
    .each(files, function(file) {
      return fs
        .stat(path + '\\' + file)
        .then(function(stats) {
          var result = {
            name: file,
            size: stats.size
          };
          if ( stats.isDirectory() ) result.file = 'folder';
          if ( stats.isFile() ) result.file = 'file'
          return Promise.resolve(result);
        });
    })
    .tap(console.log)
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.code);
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });
}
```