# Node Js how to wait till forEach is executed and get count result

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I need to get result after array loop is completed and do something with this result in Node Js project `count` and I need to check this variable after loop is completed

```
var count = 0;

myArray.forEach(element => {
    if(element == 'something'){
          count++;
    }
});


if(count == 2){
    // do smth
    }else if(count == 1){
        // do something else
    }else{
        // or do this
    }
```

currently `if` statement is being implemented before I get result from loop.

Comment: [Array.forEach is not asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)

Comment: You can shorten it as `var count = myArray.filter( s => s == "something")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter solution already provided is probably the best approach here! That said, here's some more background info:

The reason that the forEach is happening before the if block is because the forEach uses a callback, which is passed to Node's event loop to be executed later (I recommend doing some research on the event loop! Very helpful to know).

The most similar approach to yours that runs synchronously would be a standard for loop:

```
var count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(element == 'something'){
          count++;
    }
});


if(count == 2){
    // Things
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are doing an *asynchronous operation* in each iteration of `forEach`, you can shorten your code as

```
var count = myArray.filter(s => s == "something").length
```

Or something equivalent to

```
var f = str => str == "something"
var count = myArray.filter(f).length
```