# Is Array.forEach asynchronous?

Tags: javascript

According to [JavaScript, Node.js: is Array.forEach asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous), Array.forEach is synchronous. However, for my code below:

```
function wait5() {
    return new Promise(resolve => 
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
}

async function main() {
   console.log("Start");
   [1,2].forEach(async (e) => {
      const d = await wait5().then(()=> console.log("5s later") )
   })
   console.log("This should come last!");
}

main();
```

The output is:

```
Start
This should come last!
5s later
5s later
```

with the two "5s later" coming out in rapid succession.

Why is this the case?

If I use a normal `for` loop:

```
async function main() {
   console.log("Start");
   for (let i=0;i<2;i++) {
      const d = await wait5().then(()=> console.log("5s later") )
   }
   console.log("This should come last!");
}
```

then the result is what I wanted:

```
Start
5s later
5s later
This should come last!
```

Comment: The `.forEach()` mechanism *on its own* performs no asynchronous work. The same cannot be said for code that's passed in as the callback, which is free to do anything it wants.

Comment: `await` is the key here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `forEach` and everything to do with `[1,2].forEach(async (e) =>` where you declared the callback to `forEach` to be `async`.

Comment: And note that nothing pays attention to the Promise returned from each call to the `.forEach()` callback.

Comment: This is your second question about asynchronicity in JavaScript.  I'm all for that, please keep asking well formed questions.  However, is there a core question that might be better asked like "What does asynchronicity actually mean in JS?" or "How does the event loop work?"?  I'm not sure how better to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicates of [What is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous programming (in node.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16336367/1260204), [When is JavaScript synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035645/1260204), [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`forEach` is synchronous. Your particular callback function, however, is not. So `forEach` synchronously calls your function, which *starts* its work, once for each entry in the array. Later, the work that started finishes asynchronously, long after `forEach` has returned.

The issue is that your callback is `async`, not that `forEach` is asynchronous.

In general, when you're using an API like `forEach` that doesn't do anything with the return value (or doesn't expect a promise as a return value), either:

1. Don't pass it an `async` function, or
2. Ensure that you handle errors within the function itself

Otherwise, you'll get unhandled errors if something goes wrong in the function.

Or of course:

3. Use a `try`/`catch` block within the `async` function to catch and handle/report errors within the function itself.

Comment: Wouldn't the `await` call prevent the forEach iteration from continuing until the result is returned?

Comment: @OldGeezer - No. `await` pauses the callback, at which point the callback returns its promise. `forEach` continues. You can't make a synchronous function asynchronous.

Comment: I am still confused. Why does a normal `for` loop (see updated details) not behave the same?

Comment: @OldGeezer - Good question. Because a `for` loop in an `async` function is modified by the fact it's an `async` function; modifying the basic flow-control structure is what `async` on a function does. `forEach` isn't modified in that way. (It could have been, when `async` functions were added, since it's a built-in. But that would have been complicated and even more confusing. So only *syntax*, not API functions, is modified by `async`.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're declaring an `async` function inside of a caller that really doesn't care for that sort of thing, `forEach`. Declaring a function `async` makes it promise-like, but that promise is only useful if acted on.

If you need a promise-aware `forEach`, that's something you could implement, though `Promise.each` in libraries like Bluebird already do that.