# Why is my code not awaiting in a forEach when it works when I use a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs

I have a following code which creates remote folders locally if they do not exist:

```
await remoteFolders
  .filter(rf => !localFolders.some(lf => lf === rf))
  .forEach(async (rf) => await this.createFolder(rf));
```

Method createFolder looks like this:

```
async createFolder(folderPath) {
  if (!(await fs.exists(folderPath))) {
    await fs.mkdir(folderPath);
  }
}
```

The problem is that if I debug I can see that await in forEach is ignored and the loop does not wait until createFolder method finishes. So if I create directories which depend on previous ones, it obviously fails.

But if I use for-loop it works fine (await is taken into account and loop execution continues after createFolder finishes):

```
for (let i = 0; i < remoteFolders.length; i++) {
  if (!localFolders.some(lf => lf === remoteFolders[i])) {
    await this.createFolder(remoteFolders[i]);
  }
}
```

I can use this one, but using forEach looks more elegant to me. Why does not forEach take await into account?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @jbialobr `Promise.all` allows to await for all folders creation, but does not chain them

Answer (score 2):

An async function runs until it hits an `await`, and then returns a promise. ForEach doesn't do anything special when you return a promise. All it sees is that your function returned, and therefore it can move on to the next element of the array. So forEach synchronously steps through the array, calls a bunch of functions, and gets a bunch of promises back which it ignores. Later, the promises will start resolving and your functions will resume running, but this is after forEach has finished.

Comment: and is there any option how to write my code using forEach or I have to stick with classic for-loop?

Comment: @jabko87 look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous , you may use `async.each`

Comment: @sagi thanks will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

When using forEach, we specify a callback function. This callback will be executed on each element in the array. When await is used it returns a promise and nothing else. The loop continues and promise is resolved later.