# How to implement async in for loop?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I have a collection called  'alldetails' which have the details of some collection

```
{
    "name" : "Test1",
    "table_name" : "collection1",
    "column_name" : "column1"
},
{
    "name" : "Test2",
    "table_name" : "collection2",
    "column_name" : "column2"
},
{
    "name" : "Test3",
    "table_name" : "collection3",
    "column_name" : "column3"
}
```

I have collection1,collection2 and collection3 which have column1,column2,colum3 respectively

I have to fetch all the name from the  'alldetails' and I have to get the min and max value of other table based on the column name.

So I want the output like below

```
{name: ["Test1","Test2","Test3"],
date: [{min_date: "2018-12-01", max_date: "2018-12-31", name: "Test1"},
              {min_date: "2018-12-01", max_date: "2018-12-31", name: "Test2"},
              {min_date: "2018-12-01", max_date: "2018-12-31", name: "Test3"}]

}
```

I tried the below code because of non blocking its not waiting the response.

```
alldetails.find({}, { _id: 0 }).then(async function(result) { 
    let result_data = {};  
    let resolvedFinalArray = {};
    let array = [];
    result_data["name"]= [];
    result_data["date"] = [];
    resolvedFinalArray = await Promise.all(result.map(async value => { 
      result_data["name"].push(value.name)  
      getResult(value.table_name,value.column_name,function(response){
           result_data["date"].push({min_date: response.minvalue, max_date: response.maxvalue, name:value.name})          
       });     
    }));
    setTimeout(function()
    { 
      console.log(resolvedFinalArray);
    }, 3000);

});
```

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map)

Comment: I tried that also. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait for `getResult` then you need to return `Promise` from `result.map` callback.

You are not pushing anything to `resolvedFinalArray` so why bother with `console.log(resolvedFinalArray)`

```
alldetails.find({}, {_id: 0}).then(async (result) => {
    let result_data = {};
    result_data["name"] = [];
    result_data["date"] = [];
    await Promise.all(result.map(value => {
        // create Promise that resolves where getResult callback is fired
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            getResult(value.table_name, value.column_name, (response) => {
                result_data["name"].push(value.name);
                result_data["date"].push({
                    min_date: response.minvalue,
                    max_date: response.maxvalue,
                    name: value.name
                });
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }));
    console.log(result_data);
});
```

or using `for` loop

```
alldetails.find({}, {_id: 0}).then(async (result) => {
    let result_data = {};
    result_data["name"] = [];
    result_data["date"] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        const value = result[i];
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            getResult(value.table_name, value.column_name, (response) => {
                result_data["name"].push(value.name);
                result_data["date"].push({
                    min_date: response.minvalue,
                    max_date: response.maxvalue,
                    name: value.name
                });
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }
    console.log(result_data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use async.eachOfLimit if you want to apply an async function on all element of an array:

```
var async = require("async");
var array = [{_id: "...."},{...},{...}];

async.eachOfLimit(array, 1, function(element, index, cb){


    myAsyncFunctionWithMyElement(element, function(err){
        return cb(err);
    });

}, function(err){
  // final callback
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The array forEach method [won't work with async function](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) (unless you do deeply evil things like redefining the prototype). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous) has a nice insight of the internal.

If you don't want to rely on external libraries, an easy (and my favourite) approach is something like:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < <your array>.length; i++ ) {
        await Promise.all( <your logic> );
    }
```

Just adapt it to your need! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `for await of` loop. See [this blog post](http://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html) for details.

This, IMHO, is the most modern way to do it, and it doesn't require you to load any external dependencies, since it is built-in to the language itself. It's basically very similar to the classical `for of` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if all lexical scope are taken to consideration. [Async each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) is also is better option it would reduce if else blocks and manage promise for you.

```
alldetails.find({}, { _id: 0 })
    .exec((err, result) => {
        if (!err) {
            let resolvedFinalArray = [];
            result.map((value) => {
                resolvedFinalArray.push({
                    name: value.name,
                    date: []
                });
                getResult(value.table_name, value.column_name, (err, response) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        resolvedFinalArray[resolvedFinalArray.indexOf(value.name)]['date'].push({
                            min_date: response.minvalue, 
                            max_date: response.maxvalue, 
                            name:value.name
                        });
                    } else {
                        // Send your error messsage.
                        // res.status(500).send(err);            
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log(resolvedFinalArray);
            // res.send(resolvedFinalArray);
        } else {
            // Send your error messsage.
            // res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
```