# replacing for loop with forEach method

Tags: javascript

I use forEach almost every time that I'm facing a node list or an actual array, but there are times, in which I can't do so, like when I want to create 5 div elements, I'm bound to do this with for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   //my code to do some repetitive code ...

   const myDiv = document.createElement('div');
   myDiv.classList.add(`${myDiv}${i}`)
   document.appendChild(myDiv);
}
```

The question is how can I do the same work with forEach, when there is no actual array or node list that can be used forEach method.

since forEach does the work asynchronously unlike for loop, I think it would be more beneficial move, am I wrong, any idea?

Comment: _"since forEach does the work asynchronously"_ - No, it doesn't.

Comment: [Is forEach asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050265/javascript-node-js-is-array-foreach-asynchronous)? No, it's not. It doesn't take a callback and doesn't return a Promise.

Comment: That's weird I've heard that in some tutorial and he said that is one of the reason using forEach is preferred.

Comment: `[0,1,2,3].forEach((i) => {const myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.classList.add(\`${myDiv}${i}\`)
document.appendChild(myDiv);})` is the same thing as your for loop

Comment: Juan, what if I want to do it 100 times?

Comment: @Andreas Fixed :p

Comment: so you guys are saying forEach works synchronously?

Comment: @AbeIsWatching `new Array(100).forEach((_, i) => {})`

Comment: If you want to add it 100 times, stick with `for(let i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)`. There's no reason to make your life harder by absolutely wanting to switch to a more complicated solution.

Comment: `Array.from({length: 100}, (_ , i) => { const d = document.createElement("div"); d.className = "[object Object]" + i; return d; })`

Comment: If you want 100 times `new Array(100).fill(0).forEach(...)`

Comment: Also, you can `break` a for loop, and use `await` in it. Two things impossible with `.forEach()`.

Comment: Jeremy, you're telling me there is no benefit in using forEach over for loop?

Comment: @JeremyThille Just to be 100% accurate, you can also `return` from a `for` loop, which I happen to use more often than `break`.

Comment: Exactly, so, `break`, `await` and `return`, plus the absence of need to create an array in memory, are 4 good reasons to use `for` over `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array(3).fill().forEach((e,i) => {
  const myDiv = document.createElement('div');
  myDiv.classList.add(`${myDiv}${i}`)
  document.appendChild(myDiv);
})
```

Comment: To which OP responded (above) by asking, what if I want 100 iterations?

Comment: @AbeIsWatching look at the `forEach` equivalent, it's providing no real benefit, actually creating  a useless array in the memory and reducing the code readability. compare it to ur clean old school `for` loop

Comment: yeah, e represent each member of the array and i the index of that member in that array.Thanks, that is the right answer but almost every one says, stick to for loop for these cases.

Comment: @Ismail You should add the disclaimer to your answer since though it technically answers the question, you think a for loop is better. Especially considering the OP's original assumption that a `forEach` was asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in using the `for` loop, and that is exactly the right place to use a `for` loop (or a `while`).

Comment: ha, I always thought there are some benefits in using forEach over for loop even in these cases...

Comment: or even `do {...} while(++i < 100)` :)