# nodejs parallel callback design pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, concurrency, node.js, parallel-processing

I'm trying to find a good pattern to execute a bunch of parallel tasks.

Let me define some task to exemplify. Tasks `a, b, c, d, e, f, g` execute as `a(function(er, ra){//task a returned, ra is result})`, so do `b` to `g`

There are also some tasks that should be execute after some task is done, let's call them `ab, bc, abc, bd, bcd, af, fg`, means when `a` and `b` has returned `ab(ra, rb)` should be executed at once, and when `b` and `c` returned, `bc(rb, rc)` should be executed at once, and if `a`, `b`, `c` all returned, `abc(ra, rb, rc)` should be executed.

For the simplest case, if there is only `a` and `b`, I can do something like this:

```
(function(cb){
    var count = 2, _ra, _rb;
    function update(){if(--count == 0) cb(null, _ra, _rb)}
    a(function(er, ra){_ra = ra; update()});
    b(function(er, ra){_rb = rb; update()});
})(function(er, ra, rb){
    ab(ra, rb);
});
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` execute in parallel, and when both are done, `ab(ra, rb)` execute.

But how can I do more things for a lot of parallel tasks?

Answer (score 14):

What you actually want is a deferred pattern though like [futures](http://coolaj86.info/futures/).

```
function defer(f) {
    // create a promise.
    var promise = Futures.promise();
    f(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            // break it
            promise.smash(err);
        } else {
            // fulfill it
            promise.fulfill(data);
        }
    });
    return promise;
}
var da = defer(a), db = defer(b), dc = defer(c), dd = defer(d), de = defer(e), df = defer(f), dg = defer(g);

// when a and b are fulfilled then call ab
// ab takes one parameter [ra, rb]
Futures.join(da, db).when(ab);
Futures.join(db, dc).when(bc);
// abc takes one parameter [ra, rb, rc]
Futures.join(da, db, dc).when(abc);
Futures.join(db, dd).when(bd);
Futures.join(db, dc, dd).when(bcd);
Futures.join(da, df).when(af);
// where's e ?
Futures.join(df,dg).when(fg);
Futures.join(da,db,dc,dd,de,df,dg).fail(function() {
    console.log(":(");
});
```

Comment: It's almost like music it's so beautiful

Comment: Is this genuinely handling those tasks in parallel, when node.js is single threaded running in a single process?  Or is it pushing the tasks to the end of the event queue, to be handled later, when the event queue has nothing else to do?

Comment: @AntKutschera there is no multi threading. It's simply saying run a-g in parallel (there asynchronous handled by a different process in a different thread) and when any pair finishes run this function

Comment: who starts that child process?  The Futures library?  How?

Comment: @AntKutschera I assumed `a,b,c,d, etc` all either start child processes or do asynchronous IO through a socket or stream. Node does a minimal amount of lifting. Futures doesn't. Futures just says when both da and db return run ab.

Answer (score 8):

You should check out Step ( https://github.com/creationix/step ).  It's just over a hundred lines of code, so you can read the whole thing if needed.

My preferred pattern looks something like this:

```
function doABunchOfCrazyAsyncStuff() {
  Step (
    function stepA() {
      a(arg1, arg2, arg3, this); // this is the callback, defined by Step
    }
    ,function stepB(err, data) {
      if(err) throw err; // causes error to percolate to the next step, all the way to the end.  same as calling "this(err, null); return;"
      b(data, arg2, arg3, this);
    }
    ,function stepC(err, data) {
      if(err) throw err;
      c(data, arg2, arg3, this);
    }
    ,function stepDEF(err, data) {
      if(err) throw err;
      d(data, this.parallel());
      e(data, this.parallel());
      f(data, this.parallel());
    }
    ,function stepGGG(err, dataD, dataE, dataF) {
      if(err) throw err;
      var combined = magick(dataD, dataE, dataF);
      var group = this.group();  // group() is how you get Step to merge multiple results into an array
      _.map(combined, function (element) {
        g(element, group()); 
      });
    }
    ,function stepPostprocess(err, results) {
      if(err) throw err;
      var processed = _.map(results, magick);
      return processed; // return is a convenient alternative to calling "this(null, result)"
    }
    ,cb // finally, the callback gets (err, result) from the previous function, and we are done
  );
}
```

Notes

- My example also uses the underscore library, "the tie to match JQuery's tux": http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/
- Naming each step function stepXXXXX is a good habit so that the stack traces are clear and readable.
- Step lets you make powerful and elegant combinations of serial and parallel execution.  These patterns are straightforward and comprehensible.  If you need anything more complex like "when 3 of 5 of these methods completes, go to the next step", seriously RETHINK your design.  do you *really* need such a complex pattern? (maybe you are waiting for a quorum set).  Such a complex pattern deserves a function of it's own.

Comment: is group tasks are parallel or serial

Comment: There are a couple downsides to this over async, namely if you want to call a utility method, such as with waterfall, you'd need to have a wrapper to handle the err.  ex: collection.find.bind(...), where you can use function binders to methods in your chain... this is really useful, and doesn't work with step.

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [step](https://github.com/creationix/step) module and [this](http://howtonode.org/step-of-conductor) article.

Comment: That should be a compliment. Explaining how to use step is an answer.

Comment: @Raynos it took me a couple times reading that to realize I think you meant 'comment', but don't change it because that's pretty funny

Answer (score 1):

yeah, look at flow control module, like step, chain, or flow ~ and i think there is something like that in underscore.js too

Answer (score 0):

A very simple barrier just for this: https://github.com/berb/node-barrierpoints

Answer (score 0):

[nimble](http://caolan.github.io/nimble/) is another good choice.