# How long does it take to create a module / library in JavaScript for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

I have yet to learn a programming language, and I have to choose between Python and JaveScript for my project.

With Python, I know, most of the libraries are already there for me, quite ready to use. But I absolutely love the fact that if I learn JavaScript, I can do both server-side (Node.js) and client-side (jQuery) scripting in one language; plus Node.js is considerably faster than Python from what I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257362/web-frameworks-available-libraries-is-it-a-brave-move-to-opt-for-node-js-inst). And I am obessed with that.

But that also means, I might have to create my own modules/libraries from scratch for my project, due to the lack of many standard libraries in JS (at least that's what I heard). So, can someone who's been into JavaScript/Node.js/jQuery stuff please tell me this - - what's the timeframe it normally takes to complete writing a custom library in JavaScript?

Timeframe = from "time taken to write a basic library" to "time taken to write a very complex library". For example, "like 10 days to a month."

That will really help me decide whether as a beginner I can depend on JavaScript/Node.js combo for my project right from the start. Thanks.

Comment: There are tons of libraries for Node.js in fact.

Comment: An hour to a year. Not sure how to answer this question.

Comment: @pimvdb then kindly consider a scenario where I have to create a custom library that fits my needs and isn't there. *(This might seem subjective, but if you think well, it's not.)*

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">function my_alert(x) { alert(x); } </script>` There. that's a javascript library. Took about 10 seconds to write.

Comment: @MarcB: Not a nodejs library.

Comment: @thejh I wrote an adapter bridge for his library in `sed`.

Comment: subjective question, should be closed. You can probably ask over at programmers exchange though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a ton of node.js libraries for my work at [i.tv](http://i.tv). The fact is that if you know Javascript it's not that hard and there are already a ton of libraries out there. For the stuff I imagine that you want, the answer is that someone else probably already figured out how to do it. If that's not the case JavaScript is incredibly easy to learn and has a great community. Like other posters said it doesn't strictly enforce conventions or a best way, but learn from examples, see what other people are doing and ask for help on StackOverflow or IRC!

Some of the libraries that exist include database connectivity ([mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)), web-framework ([express](http://expressjs.com)), making http requests ([request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)), doing fancy stuff with dates ([moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)).

Two great places to look for node modules are:

- https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules
- http://search.npmjs.org/

For general node instructions and help, there are some great (though occasionally dated) articles on the site http://howtonode.org/. If you want to get into the knitty gritty the [node.js mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nodejs) is a great place to learn about the latest and greatest modules. A final suggestion is to following the [JSMentor's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/jsmentors). People there debate JavaScript best practices all day long.

Best of luck to getting started with node.js. It's a lot of fun.

Comment: If it's okay, can you please join me for a quick chat? **[[here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)]** I promise, it'll be quick.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there really is no answer that will mean anything to you. With no programming experience it may well take you a week to do a simple library and years to do a complex library. For an experienced programmer is may take an hour or less to make a simple library and years to make a complex one. With that in mind:

1 hour *to* 10 years to create a library from scratch.

Comment: which means there are no complex libraries available for Node.js? (I do not intent to be offensive)

Comment: No, not that there are none but you didn't specify how complex. And remember many of the complex libraries out there are useable but not done. Many are still under active development and not just in a maintenance mode.

Comment: asking out of curiosity. Would building a photo sharing site require creating complex libraries? In general sense.

Comment: A *very* simple site from someone with *no* programming experience at all, *maybe* a month or so. But time isn't what you should be looking at, heck a full complex project isn't either. Start small, learn to program in the desired language, then jump into something biger.

Answer (score 1):

I've had pleasure of learning first Python and then Node.js and it's clearly harder and slower to write production level stuff with Node.js.

- Main reason is the Javascript itself that is pretty nasty language, consider Coffeescript from beginning.
- Node.js callback based approach makes imperative coding difficult and learning curve steep
- Javascript prototype based inheritance is difficult to master compared to Python object oriented model.
- Python philosophy is that there should be one (obvious) way to do it right. Not so with Javascript.
- Node.js module documentation is usually very poor compared to Python that has of course much longer history.

At least for me writing similar library in Node.js than with Python takes roughly 50% more time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a very simple library might just take half an hour or so if all it does is creating color hashes from supplied strings. Small bindings to C++ code with four or eight methods are also doable in a few hours. However, other projects, like socket.io, need multiple contributors that constantly work on it. It's really hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do eenie minie mo and pick a language to learn first.

Your question is similar to: 
"I don't know how to write/read in Japanese or Chinese. How long will it take for me to write an article in either language"

Regardless of how you look at it, you need to learn how to "write/communicate" first. Python vs. Js shouldn't be a concern right now.