# Node.js - require is not defined exception

Tags: node.js, require

I am a complete Node.js newbie and struggling with the basics. Running this code on the server:

```
var http        = require("http"),
    sys         = require("util"),
    io          = require("socket.io"),
    GlobTrie    = require("glob-trie.js");
```

Gives me an exception at the first require:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
(anonymous function)
```

Any thoughts?

Best regards, Ben.

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: Hi @thejh
Apologies for not being clear. I have a test.html file within the Node dir. I run this locally using a browser. This loads my server.js file (with the above code) using the following:


`<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="server.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </head>`

Appreciate any comments.

Regards, Ben.

Comment: close vote because the author considers it to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case closed, I was including the wrong file on the client!

Sorry to waste people time, but thanks for the Node links.

Comment: Close this question please. If this answer is the solution, accept it.

Comment: sooo...what file DID you need on the client then?

Answer (score 2):

Node.js is run on the server side, not on the browser side.

Check out more about Node here: [What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)

Comment: Hi @alessioalex 
I am running my server code (server.js) on the server. This is running using Node. Node starts fine. I then load my test.html (see above comment) and thats what logs the exception, referencing the server.js.

Comment: Why are you trying to include server.js on the frontend..?

Comment: Hi @alessioalex
The front end script utilises the server side script also. The example I am trying is here https://github.com/rbranson/brokaw

Regards, Ben

Comment: I think that's kind of old and non-functional? Look at the notes at the bottom: Tested on node v0.2.4. Experimental etc

Comment: Yes, I did spot that, perhaps not the best intro to Node for me ;)

Given in was only a few lines of code, I was hoping to get going.

Thanks for your assistance.

Ben.

Comment: Here are some resources for learning Node: http://delicious.com/alessioaw/nodejs http://stackoverflow.com/tags/node.js/info https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Resources