# Trouble with require() at coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, require

Beginer at coffeescript. I installed coffee-script and socket.io by npm. But this simple code shows me an error:

```
try
  io = require('socket.io')
catch error
  alert(error)
```

it returns `require is no defined`.
Same problem with other modules (for example `fs`).
Using `PyCharm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - require is not defined exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404562/node-js-require-is-not-defined-exception)

Comment: How are you running your code? `require` only works in CommonJS environment (i.e. in `node.js`). You're not trying to run this code in a browser, are you?

Comment: Oh shi... But how can i use socket.io on client side for communicate with backend on Flask?

Comment: Use socket.io-client

Comment: But for use socket.io-client i need to call require('socket.io-client'). Am i right? How can i use other modules in coffee-script expect require() function?

Comment: You can use `socket.io-client` without `requirejs`, but I recommend to learn `requirejs`.

Comment: Well, you could load `socket.io-client` script in an old way, using separate `<script src="...">` tag. Or, if you really want to use modules and `require` in you client-side code, you could adopt [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or any other client-side modules system.