# How to develop a multi-tenant application with Node.js (express.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm looking for resources on how to write a multi-tenant application in Node.js. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Thanks.

Here's my technology stack:

- Node.js
- Express.js
- Mocha.js
- Postgres SQL
- JavaScript
- HTML5

Comment: what does "multi-tenant" mean? Are you talking about hosting several domains/apps at once?

Comment: By multi-tenant I mean have one central application which is accessible by tenants through sub-domains. The database is shared. Each tenant will then have it's own users. I'm basically developing a SaaS service.

Comment: take a look at virtual hosts https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/vhost/index.js You can create more than one app and share some part of the system such as the database connections.

Comment: @jsf Did you get any lead? Can you point me to some useful resources? I am at the same point where you were right now :). Let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

a pretty complete StackOverflow answer can be found here:

[How to make Node.js Multi-tenant for websites on port 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216003/how-to-make-node-js-multi-tenant-for-websites-on-port-80)

also jackdbernier has a good answer about vhosts within expressJS.