# MacOS dev box setup - which tools to install?

Tags: macos

I'm about to rebuild my Macbook - new SSD, upgrade to Lion, etc.  I have a bunch of great tools installed now that make me very productive ... vim w/ config settings, [ack](https://beyondgrep.com/), [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/#download), [underscore-cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli), etc.

I'm starting this question partly so that I can record the setup steps and tools that I myself add back.  But I also want to open it up to the community... What tools do you use on your dev box?  What utilities and customizations do you find indispensable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously the first thing I'd put on is Xcode.  Now that Xcode is a self contained app the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" are a must have. These can be downloaded from within Xcode using the following menu item, `Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> More Developer Tools`.

[CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) is very handy for quickly trying stuff out in a number of different languages.

[Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash/) is fantastic for quickly accessing API documentation for a number of different languages.  It is also a snippet manager.

[otx](http://otx.osxninja.com/) and [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) are useful tools for debugging.

[F-script](http://www.fscript.org/) for getting inside other OS X applications.

[Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) makes running multiple versions of perl simple.

[Slender](http://dragonforged.com/slender/) makes managing images in iOS apps easier by telling you which resolutions you are missing etc.

I'm sure there are many more things that I use that I've not thought of.

Answer (score 0):

### The Basics

[Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome) - needs no introduction

[Iterm2](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/) - far better terminal program than the built-in version.  Supports panes and tabs and a bunch of other nice features.

[Ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) - a superior version of grep - highlights matches, recursive by default, etc.  This is my goto tool for finding stuff in sourcecode.

---

### [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation):

The installation one-liner:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fksSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Then you need build tools (gcc, etc).  You can install these through XCode (the "normal" way), or by using [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer).

XCode is a massive 4.7G download, but it's a requirement for iOS development so I need it anyways.

With XCode: [App Store Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12), then open XCode and go to Preferences -> Download -> Install Command-line-tools

Without XCode:
If you don't need the full XCode GUI, the [osx-gcc-installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) is a DMG installer for just the command-line tools.  It's much smaller and quicker to get going.  Also doesn't require an Apple Developer account.

My Brews:

```
ack         curl        git-subtree gnu-tar     jpeg        node        xmlto
asciidoc    docbook     gnu-getopt  imagemagick libtiff     pkg-config  xz
coreutils   gettext     gnu-sed     jasper      little-cms  wget
```

---

### Vim

PCKeyboard hack (CapsLock --> ESC): http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html

https://github.com/ddopson/home

---

### Node.js

http://nodejs.org/#download

See [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js/6782438#6782438)

[underscore-cli](http://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) - great tool for parsing and processing JSON data

[jshint](http://www.jshint.com/) - more configurable version of JSLint