# Where does node.js fit in a stack or enhance it

Tags: python, node.js, web-applications

I am interested in learning more about node.js and utilizing it in a new project. The problem I am having is envisioning where I could enhance my web stack with it and what role it would play. All I have really done with it is followed a tutorial or two where you make something like a todo app in all JS. That is all fine and dandy but where do I leverage this is in a more complex web architecture.

so here is an example of how I plan on setting up my application

web server for serving views:

- Python (flask/werkzeug)
- Jinja
- nginx
- html/css/js

API sever:

- Python (flask/werkzeug)
- SQLAlchemy (ORM)
- nginx
- supervisor + gunicorn

DB Server

- Postgres

So is there any part of this stack that could be replaced or enhanced by introducing nodeJS I would assume it would be best used on the API server but not exactly sure how.

Comment: Check out the answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js

Comment: Wonder why you are getting close votes.

Comment: most questions like these are viewed as dupes or not constructive. I particularly havent seen the exact answer I am looking for so I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would replace `Python (flask/werkzeug)` in both your view server and your API server.