# mongodb Client + Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I followed the "Basic Introduction to MongoDB" from (http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html)

I installed **node-v0.8.21** from sources to this directory "**/home/myuser/lib/node/**" (I'am not root on the machine)

I set the proxy for npm and launched this command to install "mongodb" driver: "`./npm install mongodb`"
The command returned in success and produced a mongodb directory in "**/home/myuser/lib/node/bin/node_modules/**".

I don't know how to use the driver now.. 
I tried this:

```
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
if(!err) {
 console.log("We are connected");
}
});
```

But I always have this error code: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**"

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the path that this code is in?

Comment: is this server side JS (node.js) or clientside (browser)

Comment: How are you executing that code? Do other small Node.js apps work using require from the same location? That code won't work in a web page.

Comment: @thtsigma I don't know if it is what you are talking about. The code is on a web page located here on my machine: "/var/www/html/test_mongo/index.html".

Comment: @WiredPrairie where this code should be? I call this page from a web browser: "http://localhost/test_mongo/index.html"

Comment: That code only runs when executed in NodeJs. It's not for use with web pages. You need to create an API/routes/etc. to access and show the data on a web page.

Comment: Sorry for pointing this out: But you have no idea how this works. Node is in some very abstract way similar to PHP. This means: node.js runs on the server side, like PHP. The restrictions in the browser are the same as when having a website written with any other server side technology. The only thing that node.js shares with the browser is the programming language.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. You were right @Hippo.

Comment: If you are interested in using mongodb and node, 10gen provides a good abstraction layer: http://mongoosejs.com

Comment: @dethtron5000 mongoose is not written by 10gen (it's from LearnBoost),  but otherwise you are right.

Comment: @hipp oh - Doh - I thought they supported it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run server JavaScript code on browser. JavaScript is no longer a client side scripting language. `nodeJS` uses JavaScript to run a server framework, and is getting popular by the day.

> I don't know how to use the driver now.. I tried this:

People not familiar with `nodeJS` make that mistake. You have to understand that `nodeJS` is like any other server serving HTML pages. At the server you have server-side script, that executes, and client-side content that the server delivers. Only that JavaScript executes both at server and client in `nodeJS`. You should learn how to use `node` before you can learn using `mongodb` package. Here are some links:

1. [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)
2. [What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)

To test file in `nodeJS`

1. You create a file say `app.js` and put the code snippet you gave inside it. `app.js` should be immideately inside the folder where you did `./npm install mongodb`
2. Then from the same location run the app, by doing `node app.js`