# Using node.js in a production environment

Tags: node.js, webserver

I've recently begun hearing a great deal about Node.js. While I understand a few things that it's able to do, namely create a web server, I'm wondering if you could provide me with a solid reasoning behind using this functionality in a production environment.

[This article](http://alistapart.com/article/even-better-in-browser-mockups-with-node.js?utm_source=feedly) made a solid case for using Node.js as a development tool, essentially stating that it can provide the usability of a backend environment without needing backend experience. I've also heard of many developers using Node.js in production projects (Codepen for example), but I simply don't understand how it can be useful when there are established web servers out there such as a LAMP stack.

I would love to invest the time into learning about Node.js due to its growing popularity, but because I do have a fairly solid backend foundation, I'm curious if it's necessary.

In short, what are some of the most useful aspects of Node.js and why would someone need to use in a production environment?

Comment: Powerful, scalable, real-time network communication applications can benefit from node.js

Comment: This post may be of interest to you: [What is Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps the best answers can come from large companies who are using Node successfully in production.

[Why Walmart is using Node.js](http://venturebeat.com/2012/01/24/why-walmart-is-using-node-js/)

[How we build eBay's first Node.js application](http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2013/05/17/how-we-built-ebays-first-node-js-application/)

[How LinkedIn used Node.js and HTML5 to build a better, faster app](http://venturebeat.com/2011/08/16/linkedin-node/)

Scalability is often the big reason. End to end javascript is also a popular answer. Also Node is good at making some potentially complicated "real-time" scenarios almost trivial when using a library like socket.io.

And here is a [list of companies](http://nodejs.org/industry/) using Node with a short blurb on what they use it for.

Comment: Great resources. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main company behind Node.js, Joyent, is tackling this question head-on with their recent roadshow ["Node on the Road"](http://www.joyent.com/noderoad). They have collected a number of interesting testimonials of why big companies (Dow Jones, Walmart, Yahoo, etc) are using node in production. Check out [their videos section](http://www.joyent.com/noderoad/videos) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

At my company we use Node in production everywhere. We typically serve the static HTML and JS files using NGINX but smaller apps will use PM2, a Node process manager, to add clustering redundancy and auto restart to a project. [PM2 documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Example of using PM2 to maximize clusters for your Node app:

```
pm2 start -i max myNodeServer.js
```