# Node.js single threaded or not?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

I had read in Node.js processing model that node simply accept the request using event loop and give the work to c++ working threads which are performing the async operations.

I also read that :

- Node is evented not single threaded.
- In node all the things run parallel except your code.
- In node if you use settimeout function nothing will be working in that time.

I have done some research but not be able to reach to a conclusion. My question is:

- If node is using c++ working threads how can you say it is single threaded?
- how everything is parallel except our code?
- Is settimeout thing is true or not?

Comment: check out this article
http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2012/01/28/node-is-not-single-threaded.aspx

Comment: JavaScript execution in Node is single-threaded, but Node does use multiple threads (script execution is only part of the entire platform). The others are reserved for native code to implement asynchronous APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js naked runs on a single process, on a single thread.

But there is a webworker extension that allows to run more than one thread:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads

For spawning multiple processes check out the [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

(See a nice updated tutorial here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2014/02/28/taking-advantage-of-multi-processor-environments-in-node-js/)

And also the most updated answers on the topic:

[What is Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js/6782438#6782438)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8685968/1060686

Comment: All the answers related to node are almost 2 years old. I want some fresh opinion.

Comment: Well it seems for NodeJS the answer is still the same. If you don't care about using a fork, based on its reviews JXcore seems to be a pretty good one: http://jxcore.com/home/ (I haven't tried it, though)

Comment: @PankajJindal Node hasn't changed that much of its foundations within the 2 years.