# Host multiple app which has been written by node using just a single server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have just a single VPS, but i want to host multiple node.js app on it. (like Apache or nginx) 
I use nginx for proxy but there is a worry sense.
You know well; The most important features of Node are I/O non blocking and single threading. If I use this paradigm (nginx proxy), Will I miss this features ?
How I can handle this anxiety?

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js/6782438#6782438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written something about that lately, take a look: https://github.com/aspnetde/nodejs-webserver-guide