# Testing Angular with Protractor on a Sinatra server?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, testing, sinatra, protractor

I am curious as to how best to set up a testing environment for Angular on a server that is running Sinatra.  Normally when running a node server, you have a package.json which can require the dev-dependency of Protractor.  However a Sinatra server will only have a Gemfile.  Are there any best practices or gems that facilitate using Protractor in a Ruby environment?

Comment: I'd take a peak at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560204/what-is-the-use-of-node-js-in-protractor

Answer (score 0):

Protractor is a node application so you must have node install to use it. In your  case it's sounds like you will need to have both the Gemfile to maintain the dependencies for the Sinatra app and a package.json to manage dependencies for your automation tests Protractor.

You have lots of other options for end to end tests in ruby if you don't want to or don't have to use Protractor you can use rspec (the syntax for rspec and jasmine is similar) or cucumber as your testing framework and then use capybara (or selenium directly if you prefer) to control a browser and complete end to end tests.