# Why would I need Node.js if I can write code in such a way that it is always event driven

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner in writing http server code.  I'm wondering why I need node.js specifically to develop server that is non-blocking?  Can't I do that with any language that provides callbacks?

Thanks

Comment: PHP has callbacks, but no asynchronous processing model (i.e. no event loop) AFAIK. Or maybe we have different definitions of "callbacks".

Comment: well, you don't need node.js for anything. it's just another programming language, you can choose to use it or not to.

Comment: I thought node.js is just a runtime and not a language.  But how this runtime is different than if I used just the V8 runtime is confusing me

Comment: *"I thought node.js is just a runtime and not a language."* Right. However you asked whether other *languages* can do the same thing. *" But how this runtime is different than if I used just the V8 runtime is confusing me"* So a completely different question though right? V8 doesn't provide a standard library that allows you to access the file system, make network requests or provide a module system. You might want to have a look at [What is Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1884724/218196).