# NPM - Scripts - How Do They Work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, environment-variables, package.json

I cant get my head around how scripts are running within `package.json` & would appreciate some insight for us newbies.

Is it the case that they are `bash` scripts that are run by node having loaded the various `dependencies`?

If yes, then how does it process the javascript code?

Comment: Hey mate this https://www.google.bg/webhp?hl=bg&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT8L_t24LRAhWLVxoKHYH8Dc4QPAgD#hl=bg&q=how+does+package.json+work leads me to https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json which I see has a tons of info about `package.json` :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js)

Comment: `Node.js` runs JavaScript code from command line interface. `package.json` doesn't do anything, it just describes what should happen. `Node.js` parses `package.json` and reads it. It's capable of running JS, as I mentioned, which is where the magic comes from.

Comment: The question is more about the flow that I am confused about. I am aware that `node` is `javascript`. More specifically, how is the script executed? Is it that the `bash` script is run by node? Does `node` understand `bash`? Or do they communicate with eachother?

Comment: Bash script is ran by bash. Node invokes it. It's a simple system call, available to many languages (PHP uses `exec()` for such purpose), node is no exception.

Comment: Have you read `man npm`? Which leads you to `npm help 5 package.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the case that they are bash scripts

yes

> that are run by node

no, they are run by `sh`.

> having loaded the various dependencies?

no, no js files are loaded, the only thing `npm` does for you is to [prepare the environment](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts). Among other things, it adds `./node_modules/.bin` to `PATH` so you can invoke installed modules immediately.

When you run `npm run-script whatever`, this is what `npm` does:

- reads the corresponding command line from `package.json`
- prepares the environment
- invokes `sh` (or `comspec` on win) and gives it the command and the env. No big magic here.

Comment: Just for closure, sh is this -> http://superuser.com/questions/97614/what-exactly-is-the-sh-command

Answer (score 0):

This may not be 100% accurate so I implore other, more qualifies, experts to chime in.

NPM is a program, installed as part of the Node.JS environment. It's two main uses (as describe [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.htm)) are for searching for node.js packages and installing node.js packages.

However, NPM is also capable of understanding "simple" (a relative term) scripts.

When you write a script in your package.json, and issue the NPM command, say "npm start", NPM will read and interpret the script. NPM then searches your node_modules structure for the accompanying binary and executes that binary with the necessary start parameters.

An example would be

```
"test": "mocha --reporter spec test"
```

when you issue "npm test", NPM will look for the mocha binary in your node_modules structure. NPM finds mocha initiates the call, passing the reporter command arg (--reporter spec) and the name of the file to be read and executed for the test.