# What is and where is the runtime environment for 'PHP' like the 'Node.js' runtime environment for 'Javascript' to build server-side web applications?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, runtime, environment

I'm a **PHP Developer** by profession and I've never used **Node.js** in my life.

But I know that **Node.js** is a cross-platform **JavaScript runtime environment** that allows developers to build server-side and network applications with **JavaScript**.

The above statement created one query in my mind that like **Node.js** is there any **runtime environment** exist for the server-side programming language **PHP**?

I've never heard that **PHP** also has a **runtime environment** which I always hear in case of **Javascript** which has **Node.js** as a **runtime environment** to build server-side web applications.

Someone please clear my doubt in case of **runtime environment** for **PHP**. If it's present where it is and what it comprises of? If not, then explain how does **PHP** allow to build server-side applications without having a **runtime environment**?

Following is my current setup for PHP :

I'm using **PHP 7.4.2** on my laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system**.

I've installed the latest version of **XAMPP** installer on my laptop which has installed the **Apache/2.4.41 (Win64)** and **PHP 7.4.2**

Comment: Maybe you need first to read [what is Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js) ..?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to understand yours questions, but i'll try to answer you properly.
As en interpreted language I think PHP could not be considered to have runtime environment.

> I'll assume by **runtime environment** you may reference to a **complete environment isolated from the other part of the system**( like Java VM)

You can use generally PHP in two main ways:
- with a web server (websites, web apps..)
- a standalone executable (CLI scripts)

1. With a web server, you can not assume this a runtime environment as it come **separately**: webserver + php module for this webserver
2. As a standalone executable, you may have environment variables and others configurable environment elements related but this not **isolated** from the rest of the operating system:

   - It doesn't execute is own bytecode (however you could use [OPCache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php)
   - It doesn't manage it own threads : same as above you can use extension

   It's complety différent from NodeJS which use a VM(V8) from my point of view.

Comment: **Javascript** is also an **interpreted language** and it has a **runtime environment** present in form of **Node.js**. So your assumption, *"As en interpreted language I think PHP could not be considered to have runtime environment"* which means that **interpreted programming languages** can not have a **runtime environment** is false. I think whether the programming langue is interpreted or complied has nothing to do in having a **runtime environment** for that particular programming language.