# Why do I need node js and what is a framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks

so I learned HTML and CSS and now I'm learning JavaScript but I want to know what is node js and why I need it and in general what is a framework? and sorry if this question is kinda stupid :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884724/what-is-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a very high level, you code is divided into backend and frontend code. Backend code runs on 'servers', while frontend code runs directly in your browser (hence the name frontend).

Javascript on its own is considered frontend. It is used to manipulate the visual elements (DOM, HTML widgets) of a web page. Python, PHP, JAVA are considered backend. Previously, someone would write backend code say in Python and the output would be sent to the frontend where you would then use Javascript to further manipulate it (for example - hide some fields, show some fields, before displaying the data).

Node allows you to write backend code in Javascript. This means that if you already know Javascript, you don't have to go learn another programming language like Python or JAVA to write backend code. You can create your backend code in Javascript (using Node).

Comment: so I will only need it when I start writing the back end? cause rn I'm learning front end web development

Comment: From the Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) definition - Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform, back-end JavaScript runtime environment that runs on the V8 engine and executes JavaScript code outside a web browser.